# Java Serializable Object to Byte Array

Tags: java, object, serialization

Let's say I have a serializable class `AppMessage`.

I would like to transmit it as `byte[]` over sockets to another machine where it is rebuilt from the bytes received.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Why as `byte[]`? Why not just write it directly to the socket with `ObjectOutputStream`, and read it with `ObjectInputStream`?

Comment: use apache camel

Comment: `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(JAVA_OBJECT_HERE)`

Answer (score 459, accepted):

Prepare the byte array to send:

```java
static byte[] serialize(final Object obj) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
        out.writeObject(obj);
        out.flush();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Create an object from a byte array:

```java
static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    try (ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
        return in.readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how I read the question. To me it sounds like his problem is how to convert the object to a byte[] -- not how to send it.

Comment: Taylor: yes you got it right. i want to turn the object into a byte[] and transmit it. can you please also provide the code regarding how to turn this byte[] into an object please?

Comment: Please close always any stream to release the system resources. (Edited in code)

Comment: can this work with objects that I can't implement serializable?

Comment: how do you deal with the uncaught exceptions on the statements in the "finally" block?

Comment: thank you so much.  this works great sending a custom Settings object (with loads of settings) from android phone to android watch as a byte[]

Comment: The original closed out but it was edited away. See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2836659/revisions.

Comment: `ObjectInput`, `ObjectOuput`, `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream` all implement the `AutoCloseable` interface, wouldn't it be good practice to use it to avoid missing closing them by mistake? (I'm not entirely sure if this is the best practice, that's why I'm wondering.) Example: `try(ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)){ /*Do stuff*/ }catch(IOException e){/*suppress exception*/}`. It also removes the need for the `final` clause and its additional `try-catch`.

Comment: @LudvigRydahl: answer comes from 2010, Java7 (and try-with-resource) comes from 2011. Otherwise yes, try-with-resource is a good practice - however, that does not apply to the "suppress" part, which is a bad practice.

Comment: @tevemadar that is true about Java 7.however I only posted suppress,which in most cases is a terrible handling, since the answer said ignore.

Comment: @LudvigRydahl: Note that the answer ignores exception from resource.close() only. Using try-with-resource, you just close the block and you have the same thing as in the answer (there is no catch in it either, only the finally)

Comment: @Esko There is nothing in the question about RMI or obect construction and deconstruction whatsoever, and this answer covers both serialization and serialization mechanisms.

Answer (score 343):

The best way to do it is to use `SerializationUtils` from Apache [Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

To serialize:

```
byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize(yourObject);
```

To deserialize:

```
YourObject yourObject = SerializationUtils.deserialize(data)
```

---

As mentioned, this requires Commons Lang library. It can be imported using Gradle:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
```

Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

[Jar file](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar)

And more ways mentioned [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.5)

Alternatively, the whole collection can be imported. Refer [this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1)

Comment: Added overhead? Might as well rebuild the wheel at this point. Seriously, it's much more easy to understand this one-liner and reduce possible errors (like not closing the stream at right time and whatnot).

Comment: Best way because you use a common library offering you:
1) Robustness: People are using this and thus it is validated to work.
2) It does the above (most popular answer) with only 1 line so your code stays clean.
3) Because Dan said so.
4) I'm just kidding regarding to 3 :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the method restricts the output size to 1024. If one needs to convert a file to a byte stream, better not use this.

Comment: I would not prefer this one for microservices. The library could make them heavier is size, than direct methods.

Comment: to use ``SerializationUtils.serialize(o)``, your object need this ``implements Serializable``

Comment: @zon so the accepted answer is better than this method if we want to keep the size of the application small?

Comment: @y_159 The accepted answer is a bit outdated. Romero's one is neater as it uses try-with-resources.

Comment: @Abilash 1024 is the initial size and the limit doesn't apply as gzg confirmed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50344173/2002724 and I verified the source code as well

Comment: Be careful of certain versions of Apache Commons's (de)serialization library if you are trying to sandbox the application! There are known vulnerabilities regarding custom deserialization methods. Use a SecurityManager or update to the newest Apache Commons version

Answer (score 103):

If you use Java >= 7, you could improve the accepted solution using [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
private byte[] convertToBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
        out.writeObject(object);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    } 
}
```

And the other way around:

```
private Object convertFromBytes(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
        return in.readObject();
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is not quite the same than the accepted solution as the written data is not flushed before method `toByteArray()` is invoked, i.e. it could happen that some data remains in internal buffers and that not all data is transferred to the returned byte[] array. I have not found a specification of the ObjectOutputStream which describe buffer behavior.

Answer (score 14):

Can be done by **[SerializationUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html)**, by serialize & deserialize method by ApacheUtils to convert object to byte[] and vice-versa , as stated in @uris answer.

To convert an object to byte[] by serializing:

```
byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize(object);
```

To convert byte[] to object by deserializing::

```
Object object = (Object) SerializationUtils.deserialize(byte[] data)
```

Click on the link to [Download org-apache-commons-lang.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/org-apache/org-apache-commons-lang.jar.zip)

Integrate .jar file by clicking:

**FileName** -> **Open Medule Settings** -> **Select your module** -> **Dependencies** -> **Add Jar file** and you are done.

**Hope this helps**.

Comment: never add a dependency like this, use maven/gradle to download dependency and add it to the build path

Answer (score 7):

Another interesting method is from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

`byte[] data = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(JAVA_OBJECT_HERE)`

Maven Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

I also recommend to use SerializationUtils tool. I want to make a ajust on a wrong  comment by  @Abilash. The `SerializationUtils.serialize()` method is *not* restricted to 1024 bytes, contrary to another answer here.

```
public static byte[] serialize(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(object);
        oos.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to serialize object of type: " + object.getClass(), ex);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

At first sight， you may think that `new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024)` will only allow a fixed size. But if you take a close look at the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, you will figure out the the stream will grow if necessary:

> This class implements an output stream in which the data is
>   written into a byte array. The buffer automatically grows as data
>   is written to it.
>   The data can be retrieved using `toByteArray()` and
>   `toString()`.

Comment: can you add how to do the reverse? so byte[] to object?
I know others have this, but I like your answer a lot more and I can't get the deserialisation to work.
I want to avoid returning null in any case.

Comment: I was also skeptical about this code after reading @Abilash answer. But you cleared me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using spring, there's a util class available in spring-core. You can simply do

```
import org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils;

byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(anyObject);
Object object = SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
```

Comment: @PaleBlueDot yes it is, if you go to the method and see the implementation, you could see that it doesn't involve any global member.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to transmit it as byte[] over sockets to another machine

```
// When you connect
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
// When you want to send it
oos.writeObject(appMessage);
```

> where it is rebuilt from the bytes received.

```
// When you connect
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
// When you want to receive it
AppMessage appMessage = (AppMessage)ois.readObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Framework `org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils`

```
byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a nice no dependencies copy-paste solution. Grab the code below.

## Example

```
MyObject myObject = ...

byte[] bytes = SerializeUtils.serialize(myObject);
myObject = SerializeUtils.deserialize(bytes);
```

## Source

```
import java.io.*;

public class SerializeUtils {

    public static byte[] serialize(Serializable value) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try(ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out)) {
            outputStream.writeObject(value);
        }

        return out.toByteArray();
    }

    public static <T extends Serializable> T deserialize(byte[] data) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try(ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data)) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) new ObjectInputStream(bis).readObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an optimized code form of the accepted answer in case anyone wants to use this in production :

```
    public static void byteArrayOps() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    String str="123";
     byte[] yourBytes = null;

    // Convert to byte[]

    try(ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out =  new ObjectOutputStream(bos);) {


      out.writeObject(str);
      out.flush();
      yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();

    } finally {

    }

    // convert back to Object

    try(ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourBytes);
            ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);) {

      Object o = in.readObject(); 

    } finally {

    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to implements Serializable or exception will be your destiny

```
public class Dto implements Serializable {


private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Integer myNumber;
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Integer getMyNumber() {
    return myNumber;
}

public void setMyNumber(Integer myNumber) {
    this.myNumber = myNumber;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Dto{" +
            "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", myNumber=" + myNumber +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dto dto=new Dto();
    dto.setFirstName("Sajjad");
    dto.setLastName("ahmed");
    dto.setMyNumber(0305);


    byte[] serializedDto = serializeObject(dto);


    System.out.println("Serialized Dto=== " + new String(serializedDto));


    Dto deserializedDto = deserializeObject(serializedDto);


    System.out.println("Deserialized Dto===" + deserializedDto);




}



private static byte[] serializeObject(Dto dto) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutputStream);


        objectOutputStream.writeObject(dto);


        objectOutputStream.close();
        byteOutputStream.close();


        return byteOutputStream.toByteArray();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }}
    private static Dto deserializeObject(byte[] byteArray) {
        try {

            ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteInputStream);


            Dto deserializedObject = (Dto) objectInputStream.readObject();


            objectInputStream.close();
            byteInputStream.close();

            return deserializedObject;

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

code example with java 8+:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

private String lastName;
private String firstName;

public Person() {
}

public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "firstName: " + firstName + ", lastName: " + lastName;
}
}


public interface PersonMarshaller {
default Person fromStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    try (ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream)) {
        Person person= (Person) objectInputStream.readObject();
        return person;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

default OutputStream toStream(Person person) {
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        objectOutput.writeObject(person);
        objectOutput.flush();
        return outputStream;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}

}
```