# why we use prefix "java.io." everytime and not import java.io.Serializable interface

Tags: java, serialization, import

My question is NOT regarding understanding the technical understanding of usage of Serializable interface. 
Those answers has already been explained [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441196/why-java-needs-serializable-interface) & [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548816/when-should-we-implement-serializable-interface) among [others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=why%20java.io.Serializable)

My question is from syntactical point of view.

While watching the source code of Collection interface and its sub-interfaces I noticed most of the interfaces implements `Cloneable` and `java.io.Serializable` as shown below :

```
public class TreeSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E>
implements NavigableSet<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable{
...
}


public class LinkedHashSet<E>
extends HashSet<E>
implements Set<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {
...
}

public class HashSet<E>
extends AbstractSet<E>
implements Set<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {
...
}
```

...and so on

I also noticed :

- `Collection` interface , `TreeSet` `LinkedHashSet` etc. belongs to `package java.util;`
- `Cloneable` interface belongs to `package java.lang;`
- `Serializable` belongs to `package java.io;`

Now my question is why are we adding the prefix `java.io` before `Serializable`(as shown above) and not import `import java.io.Serializable;` as done in Collection interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes you have mentioned (`TreeSet`, `LinkedHashSet` etc.) doesn't have any imports at all and always use full class name if it belongs to the packages other than `java.lang` or `java.util`

I would say that it is a bad practice, but we cannot blame Mr. Josh Bloch :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how Java imports work:

- all classes and interfaces in `java.lang` are automatically visible.
- any class or interface in the same package are automatically visible to other classes and interfaces in that package.
- any class or interface in another package must be explicitly declared (package & classname) or imported.

Given these rules:

- `AbstractSet`, `NavigableSet` are in the same package as `TreeSet` and therefore automatically visible.
- `Cloneable` is in `java.lang` which is automatically visible.
- `Serializable` is in `java.io`and so explicitly declared (but would also work with an import).

In asking why you would use an explicit declaration or an import in most cases it's down to style.  In most cases an import is used as it keeps the code cleaner.

The only exception to this would be when two or more classes or interfaces with the same name are being used.  In this situation you should declare each use explicitly.

Comment: as suggested by @Kayaman could it be really to distinguish from `sunw.io.Serializable` (in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27963276/1851302))

Comment: that's possibly why, though `sunw.io.Serializable` was deprecated many years ago and I'd certainly assume that when I see Serializable it's `java.io.Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interface `sunw.io.Serializable`, so they most likely wanted to distinguish those two. However it's impossible to say what was the actual reason for this. Maybe it was policy, maybe they had run into difficult to debug bugs due to importing the wrong one...

Answer (score 0):

There is no great rationale behind this. The classes have no other import statements and `Serializable` is referred to at just one place in those files, so it is easy to see why the author may have preferred not to import.

As an another point of interest, `TreeMap` in OpenJDK 8 both contains the import statement and uses the fully-qualified name.

Comment: My installed java 'jdk1.7.0_51' TreeMap doesn't have any import BUT uses `java.io.Serializable` as reported for other cases.

Comment: Given no special qualification you should assume that I am talking about the *current* OpenJDK version (it is 8 at the time of this writing).