# Why InvalidClassException is not thrown when I have deserialized in the parent class

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Why I don't have an error while I am trying to read Child class into Parent's class variable?
I thought that before asigning object that have been read compiler checks `serialVersionUID` of both classes (variable class and class that have been read) and if `serialVersionUID` is not equal `InvalidClassException` is thrown. So does `A` class and `B` class have the same `serialVersionUID`?

```
import java.io.*;

class A  {}

class B extends A implements Serializable {}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("b.bin");
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        B b1 = new B();
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(b1);
        objectOutputStream.close();
        
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("b.bin");
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        A a1 = (A) objectInputStream.readObject(); // why I don't have an InvalidClass Exception here
        objectInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should we implement Serializable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548816/when-should-we-implement-serializable-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these two classes do not have the same `serialVersionUID`. There is no exception thrown because class `B` can be reconstructed successfully. There would for example be an *InvalidClassException* when the `serialVersionUID` would not match or when `A` would not implement a default constructor.

When you deserialise with `objectInputStream.readObject()`, an `Object` is returned which can be cast safely to `B`. Since `B` extends `A`, it can be upcasted to an object of type `A` – as it happens in your code.

*On a sidenote, I strongly suggest that you define a `serialVersionUID` for your classes if you are directly storing and retrieving objects using serialisation.*

---

You can get the `serialVersionUID` of the two classes as follows:

```
ObjectStreamClass.lookup(A.class).getSerialVersionUID()
ObjectStreamClass.lookup(B.class).getSerialVersionUID()
```

Comment: I got this, but how JVM knows  which class I want to deserialize? I mean why ```objectInputStream.readObject()```  return exactly ```B``` class if it see only ```serialVersionUID```?

Comment: @Denis_newbie The metadata is stored in the serialised stream according to the [Grammar for the Stream Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#a10258). This includes the full classname including package after the `TC_CLASSDESC` constant. You can have a look at the stored file (`b.bin`) and inspect it's content. An option would be `hexdump -C b.bin`.