# How to split getExtras() sending from getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

Tags: android

I have two class first is PageOne and Second is PageTwo, PageOne has list of content and on click on content, that content pass to PageTwo Class.

PageOne Class Using this code to track click contents

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String s = (lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

        Intent i=new Intent(PageOne.this, PageTwo.class);
        i.putExtra("name", s);
        startActivity(i);



    }
```

and PageTwo class can catch that content using this code

```
TextView Textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleidview);
Intent iin = getIntent();
Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
if (b != null) {
    String j = (String) b.get("name");
    Textv.setText(j);
}
```

when this String j output is:

**{description=description about selected, title=selected title}**

I searching a way for **display description on one TextView and title in another TextView**. How to do this, I **can do this using split function**. But I am searching a better way than using split.

Thank you...

Comment: Is you are using json?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Yes Sir

Comment: See this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649728/android-cannot-pass-intent-extras-though-alarmmanager/18649849#18649849

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
Intent iin = getIntent();
Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
if (b != null) {
    String j = (String) b.get("name");
    JSONObject name = new JSONObject(j);

    Textv.setText(name.getString("title"));
    TextvDesc.setText(name.getString("description"));
}
```