# Using intents to pass data between activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass the data between Activities

I use intents to pass data between regular activities

consider the code below::

`AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.java`

```
public class AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView extends TabActivity {

    // TabSpec Names
    private static final String INBOX_SPEC = "Rating";
    private static final String OUTBOX_SPEC = "Price";

    Button Photos;
    Button Filter;
    Button Search;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Inbox Tab
        TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
        Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.class);
        inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC);
        // Tab Content
        inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

        // Outbox Tab
        TabSpec PriceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);
        Intent PriceIntent = new Intent(this, PriceDescriptionSearchActivity.class);
        PriceSpec .setIndicator(OUTBOX_SPEC);
        PriceSpec.setContent(PriceIntent);


        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); 
        tabHost.addTab(PriceSpec); 

        //Set the current value tab to default first tab
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }

}
```

---

Suppose i send data from Someother activity called `Activity-1` to `AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView` as intents

Now how can i recieve the data in `AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView` which i got from `Activity-1` and then again pass it into `RatingDescriptionSearchActivity`

**Pictoral representation is** ::

[image]

**{EDIT}** -- If this is possible based on answers --- Ambiguity because AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView is a tab activity

```
TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
        Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, RatingDescriptionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("keyName", value);
        inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC);
        // Tab Content
        inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);
```

Comment: see this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649728/android-cannot-pass-intent-extras-though-alarmmanager/18649849#18649849

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Pass the data from `Activity-1` to `AndroidTabRes..` as below:

At sending activity...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current.this, AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

At `AndroidTabRes..` activity...

```
  String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
```

Thus you can have data at receiving activity from sending activity...

And in your `AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView` class, do this:

```
String value= getIntent().getStringExtra("keyName");

Intent intent = new Intent(this, RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your `RatingDescriptionSearchActivity` class, do this:

```
 String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("keyName");
```

Comment: Please look at the updated question ..... my ambuiguity lies because one of them is tab activity ....... Am i following correct way based on your answer ..look at the edit

Comment: Then what is your problem ?

Comment: In the edit .... Have i mentioned proper way of passing data .... because in tabactivity ... we never use startActivity(--); so ... i am confused !

Comment: That doesn't make any difference you can pass and get the data as i have shown.

Comment: what if the activity is already running, is there need to do `startActivity(i);` ? I mean, can I make *activity A* call *activity B*, and that returns data to *activity A* ? am I confused ?

Answer (score 7):

Try this from your `AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView` activity

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(this,RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.class );
intent.putExtras( getIntent().getExtras() );
startActivity( intent );
```

And then from `RatingDescriptionSearchActivity` activity just call

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("key")
```

Comment: please look at the edited question .... my ambiguity is because middle activity is a tab activity

Comment: The answer is still the same, you must send an `Intent` from first activity to `TabActivity` and when you want to fire third activity you must perform the answer setup.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Bundle to get data :

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String data = extras.getString("data"); // use your key
```

And again you can opass this data to next activity :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, next_Activity.class);
   intent.putExtra("data", data);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what if the activity is already running, is there need to do `startActivity(i);` ? I mean, can I make *activity A* call *activity B*, and that returns data to *activity A* ? am I confused ?

Comment: You can use `StartActivityForResult` to get back result to Activity A from B when it finishes....

Comment: Great, that seams useful !. Do you know if `StartActivityForResult` can be used with an `AsynkTask` ?

Comment: yeah..you can use it in `AsynkTask ` too.... :) and great to see that it's useful for u .. :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

Assuming that in your `Activity-1`, you did this:

```
String stringExtra = "Some string you want to pass";

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.class);

//include the string in your intent
intent.putExtra("string", stringExtra);

startActivity(intent);
```

And in your AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView class, do this:

```
//fetch the string  from the intent
String extraFromAct1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("string");

Intent intent = new Intent(this, RatingDescriptionSearchActivity.class);

//attach same string and send it with the intent
intent.putExtra("string", extraFromAct1);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your RatingDescriptionSearchActivity class, do this:

```
String extraFromAct1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("string");
```

Answer (score 3):

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText user, password;
    Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);

                String uservalue = user.getText().toString();
                String name_value = password.getText().toString();
                String password_value = password.getText().toString();

                intent.putExtra("username", uservalue);
                intent.putExtra("password", password_value);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Second Activity** in which you want to receive Data

```
public class Second extends Activity{

    EditText name, pass;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        String pass_val = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
        name.setText(value);
        pass.setText(pass_val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***In FirstActivity:***

```
Intent sendDataToSecondActivity = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
sendDataToSecondActivity.putExtra("USERNAME",userNameEditText.getText().toString());
sendDataToSecondActivity.putExtra("PASSWORD",passwordEditText.getText().toString());
startActivity(sendDataToSecondActivity);
```

***In SecondActivity***

In `onCreate()`

```
String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
String passWord = getIntent().getStringExtra("PASSWORD");
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this clean code to pass one value only:

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, YourActivity.class).putExtra("key","value"));
```

This make more simple to write and understandable code.