# how to pass map path state to another activity android google map

Tags: android, google-maps

in my app user should mark start point then path should be drew and then when user clicked button this path should be displayed in new activity 
how to display this path in another activity 
this is my code
and sorry for bad English

```
package com.example.project;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;



import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

public class  AirportActivity extends Activity implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener, OnMarkerClickListener{    
    boolean markerClicked;
     PolylineOptions rectOptions;
     Polyline polyline;
      GoogleMap googleMap;
      List<LatLng> points;
     List<Polyline> polylines;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.airportactivity);

    googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.mapView)).getMap();
    //googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
//  googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    polylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
     String[] placeNames = {"Cairo International Airport","Alexandria International Airport","Borg El Arab Airport",
            "Marsa Matrouh Airport","Sharm el-Sheikh International Airport","Taba International Airport","El Kharga Airport",
            "Assiut Airport","Luxor International Airport","Aswan International Airport","El Arish International Airport",
            "St. Catherine International Airport","Sharq Al-Owainat Airport","Abu Simbel Airport","Sohag International Airport",
            "Port Said Airport","El Tor Airport","Dakhla Oasis Airport","Marsa Alam International Airport","Cairo West Air Base","Almaza Air Force Base"};
     String[] placeNamesSnippet = {"Cairo International Airport1","Alexandria International Airport2","Borg El Arab Airport3", "Marsa Matrouh Airport4","Sharm el-Sheikh International Airport5","Taba International Airport6","El Kharga Airport7", "Assiut Airport8","Luxor International Airport9","Aswan International Airport10","El Arish International Airport11", "St. Catherine International Airport12","Sharq Al-Owainat Airport13","Abu Simbel Airport14","Sohag International Airport15", "Port Said Airport16","El Tor Airport17","Dakhla Oasis Airport18","Marsa Alam International Airpor19t","Cairo West Air Bas20e","Almaza Air Force Base21"};
     Double[] placeLatitude =  {30.111370, 31.192553, 30.917138,31.324435,27.978620,29.590988,27.188222,27.047695, 25.670264,
            23.960397,31.076449,28.684537,22.580600,22.375813,26.331926,31.281150,28.208842,25.688581,25.558141,
            30.116704,30.095975};
     Double[] placeLongitude = {31.413910, 29.953141,29.693375, 27.222200,34.393354,34.778946 , 33.800840, 31.013473 , 32.704063,
            32.821163,33.832256,34.062882, 28.720754, 31.611667,31.728437,32.242223,33.645257,28.972356,34.582821,
            30.916667,31.362748};
    for(int i = 0 ; i<21;i++)
      {
          googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .snippet(placeNamesSnippet[i])
                  .position(new LatLng(placeLatitude[i], placeLongitude[i]))
                  .title(placeNames[i]));

        points.add(new LatLng(placeLatitude[i], placeLongitude[i]));

 markerClicked = false;
}    
     markerClicked = false; 
      googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
      googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    if(points.size() > 2)
    {
        FindShortestPath();
    }
    else if(points.size() == 2)
    { if(markerClicked){

  if(polyline != null){
   polyline.remove();
   polyline = null;
  }
  rectOptions.add(marker.getPosition());
  rectOptions.color(Color.RED);
  polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
 }else{
  if(polyline != null){
   polyline.remove();
   polyline = null;
  }

  rectOptions = new PolylineOptions().add(marker.getPosition());
  markerClicked = true;
 }
}
 return true;
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.ListMapActivity"));
    }    
public static double distance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
    double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
    double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
    double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
    double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    return 6366000 * c;
}
// calculate distances matrix then get shortest path then call draw
public void FindShortestPath()
{
TSPNearestNeighbour tsp = new TSPNearestNeighbour();
int adjacencyMatrix[][] = new int[points.size()][];
int counter = 0,innerCounter ;
int[] result = new int[points.size()];

for(LatLng point : points)
{
    innerCounter=0;
    adjacencyMatrix[counter] = new int[points.size()];
    for(LatLng point1 : points)
    {
        if(point.equals(point1))
        {
            adjacencyMatrix[counter][innerCounter] =  0;
        }
        else 
            adjacencyMatrix[counter][innerCounter] =(int) distance(point,point1);
            innerCounter ++;
    }
    counter ++;
}
result = tsp.tsp(adjacencyMatrix);
DrawShortestPath(result);
}
//draws the shortest path with markers 
public void DrawShortestPath(int[] path)
{

    googleMap.clear();

int numOfNodes = points.size();
for(LatLng point : points)
{
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
               .position(point));
}
for (int index = 0 ; index < numOfNodes-1 ; index++)
{
     googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
.add(points.get(path[index]), points.get(path[index+1]))
.width(3)
.color(Color.RED));
}
}
class TSPNearestNeighbour
{
private int numberOfNodes;
private Stack<Integer> stack;

public TSPNearestNeighbour()
{
    stack = new Stack<Integer>();
}

public int[] tsp(int adjacencyMatrix[][])
{
    numberOfNodes = adjacencyMatrix[0].length ;
    int[] result = new int[adjacencyMatrix[0].length];
    int resultCounter = 1;
    int[] visited = new int[numberOfNodes];
    visited[0] = 1;
    stack.push(0);
    int element, dst = 0, i;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    boolean minFlag = false;
    result[0] = 0;

    //System.out.print(1 + "\t");

    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        element = stack.peek();
        i = 0;
        min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while (i < numberOfNodes)
        {
            if (adjacencyMatrix[element][i] > 1 && visited[i] == 0)
            {
                if (min > adjacencyMatrix[element][i])
                {
                    min = adjacencyMatrix[element][i];
                    dst = i;
                    minFlag = true;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (minFlag)
        {
            visited[dst] = 1;
            stack.push(dst);
            result[resultCounter] = dst;
            resultCounter++;
            //System.out.print(dst + "\t");
            minFlag = false;
            continue;
        }
        stack.pop();
    }
    return result;
}

}
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the information as arrays, you can pass them as extras in the `Intent` you are using to start the new activity.

Modify your on click like so:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent i = new Intent("net.learn2develop.ListMapActivity");
i.putExtra("latitudes", placeLatitude);
i.putExtra("longitudes", placeLongitude);
//call putExtra(key, value) for each array you want to pass to the other activity
startActivity(i);
}
```

You can read more about passing values between activities [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286970/using-intents-to-pass-data-between-activities-in-android) or in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Comment: what do u mean with so on for the other info ? if i want to share the drawing path only i modify what u say ?

Comment: I updated my answer with more info. You need to read a bit more on the official documentation to figure this out.

Comment: this is my modify but it get error in placeLatitude