# send data from Mainactivity to Mainactivity2

Tags: android, android-activity

i want to learn how to send message data from 1 activity to another and receive the data in **onActivityResult**

i am not sure if this is the right way but hope you can show me the right way.

**Mainactivity**
on button1 click

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("demo1");
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
```

**on button2 click**

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("sarah22");
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
```

**Mainactivity2**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


            if ("demo1") {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "button1 demo1 received";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

            }



if ("sarah22") {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Button2 sarah22 received";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your code not working?

Comment: no sir as i am new i am trying to figure out how this is done, i am a visual basic 6 and .net developer and now trying to learn about this its fun kindly show me an example soham will be greatfull to learn from your example basic cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage start activity for result on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to clarify my self again. I wish to use something like this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("demo1");
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
```

or maybe

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, New2.class);
                intent.putExtra("demo1", "demo1");
                startActivity(intent);
```

where you see demo1  you normally will put a requestcode there but how do I send this off to the activity2 and from their

**in activity2**

```
if ("demo1") {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "button1 demo1 received";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

            }
```

where you see  **if ("demo1") {**   if this string is found then show toast

Comment: This is not an answer. You should use the [edit] button and add this to the question if it is part of the question, otherwise people will think it is an answer and you will get no more answers.....

Answer (score 0):

You should to this:

```
          Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Second.class);
          intent.putExtra("ID", "I love stackoverflow");
          startActivityForResult(intent)
```

In the second activity you can grab the data,

```
         String id = intent.getStringExtra("ID");
```

and do what you want with it. To return to the first activity please use setResult(OK) and call finish.

```
  Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
  setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
  finish();
```

in this case the first activity onActivityResult() going to fire and you can handler the returned value there.

sources:
[Using intents to pass data between activities in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286970/using-intents-to-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)

Comment: don`t forget the String id at the second activity to check for null.