# get user inputs from an editText and populate listView

Tags: android

How can i get user inputs from one activity and `populate the listView` with user data in another activity. I am able to get user input and populate the listView in the same activity. but now i want to get user inputs in one form and populate the list in another activity.

the code that i used to populate the listView by getting user input is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

/** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    /** Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    /** Defining a click event listener for the button "Add" */
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            String name=edit.getText().toString();
            list.add(name);
            edit.setText("");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    /** Setting the event listener for the add button */
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: You can pass your data via intent.
reference link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286970/using-intents-to-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: If you'd want to pass a large amount of data, @Sarah's answer is good. However if your data is only a single string you could consider passing it by `Intent`.

Answer (score 2):

1. you can store your user input / data into a local database; that will allow you to access your data anywhere in the app 
   (recommended since you are dealing with `listview`).
2. you can use `shared preferences` to store data if your data is relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

In your current Activity (activity contains your button), create a new Intent:

```
String name = ""; 
name = edit.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("keyword",name);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the NewActivity (activity contains your Listview), retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String name = extras.getString("keyword");
    if(name != ""){
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

It is simple way, hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Declare a public method in second Activity like

**SecondActivity.class**

```
public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

/** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter

onCreate()
{
...
;
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
...
}

public static void ModifyList()
{
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**FirstActivity.class**

```
 View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            String name=edit.getText().toString();
            SecondActivity.list.add(name);
            edit.setText("");
            SecondActivity.ModifyList();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Send your ArrayList like this from FirstActivity :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Datalist",list);
    startActivity(intent);
```

In secondActivity Recieve the list using :

```
  Intent i = getIntent();  
  list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("Datalist");
```

Then display it in your SecondActivitys listview