# How to pass message to Bluetooth Activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-bluetooth, android-handler

I build an Android app that control RC car. This app have two activities, Bluetooth Activity and Direction Activity.

In Bluetooth activity I used list view to list all the devices and connect with one. I used the two class provided by Android ["ConnectThread" and "ConnectedThread"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). My main job is to only send character to the RC car to move. This character is generated by the Direction Activity which use Acceleration sensor to generate a character.

**Problems:**
1. how to send character from the Direction Activity to the Bluetooth activity?
2. After the Bluetooth Activity received the character how to send it over the Bluetooth connection?
3. Do I need the two classes "ConnectThread" and "ConnectedThread" to connect and send or just one of them?

PS. I am beginner and I have tried many things like intent, shared Preference, and Bundle. But every time I try an error occur.

Comment: For your first question use intent and pass appropriate data in intent calling

Comment: Your second question: You usually write the value to a characteristic or service. These are very basic principles that are demonstrated in the Bluetooth LE example project Android offers. The same goes for question 3. Maybe you should read up on that first, or provide some code that you've tried.

Comment: @Zimano I believe that he is using classic Bluetooth and not BLE according to the mention of ConnectThread and ConnectedThread. This Google guide explains everything but uses a hell of a pattern that is almost unreadable and too long instead on focusing on the most import parts. This is the second question I saw today mentionning this guide and I myself had trouble when I started with it from scratch not knowing a damn thing about Bluetooth...

Comment: @Mackovich I understand where you're coming from, I shouldn't have commented that based on assumptions alone. However, in defense of that Google guide; when I first started with Bluetooth I _did_ find it incredibly helpful actually! I guess it differs per person. However, I do agree that the guide is quite a hell to get through, haha.

Comment: @Zimano yes you are right because this guide lays the base of everything you need to get going with an app that acts both as client and as server. It's just hard to understand everything with this weird way of subclassing Thread ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, let's make it simple for the moment.

As stated by @Zimano comments:

1. You can use, like you tried, **intents** to share basic data
   (Strings, ints, floats, bytes) between your Activities, that is the
   most common way to do in Android. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19287072/3535408
2. If you need to send data over the Bluetooth connexion, you have to
   have access to the ConnectedThread if you implemented Google's
   solution. But if you are the beginner you say you are (and it's not
   a problem or wrong) **be aware** that Android Activities have a [life
   cycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). This basically means that at some point an Activity is
   **created**, **starts**, **stops** and finally ends up utterly **destroyed**. So if
   you started your **Connection and Connected threads** inside an Activity
   and you switch to another Activity, there is high and unvoidable
   risk that **these threads will be killed** as the Activity that started
   them is being **destroyed** for liberating resources (dearly important
   to the Android eco-system).

Two solutions. One easy but not recommandable, and one a bit complicated but part of the Android SDK and policy.

1. Static Context or
2. Services ;

In the first case, move all the code related to the Bluetooth outside your Activity into another class. Place it in a static context so that it can be used everywhere in the app (which is why it's a very poor design pattern but a working one...). Then you can access your Bluetooth threads everywhere and you can use the write method to send data ;

In the second case, move the same code into a service. Services are part of the Android SDK and are the way-to-go for what you want to achieve. But there are bind to an Activity. I did not handle a lot of Services in my experience so I am not sure if you can bind/unbind Android services at will whithout stopping the Bluetooth threads alonside as you switch between activities. More details here : http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/services.html

Anyway I hope I provided enough explaination so that you can work on your issue. If you have questions I will try to answer them.

Comment: Solid answer; I like that you provided two solutions for the OP to try. Intents are also used in the Bluetooth sample project to pass things around, so that fits nicely if the OP would be using this guide/example project.

Answer (score 0):

@Mackovich Thank you very much and also the others who tried to help. For the sake of other people who is having same problem. this is my solution after searching for long time.

P.S one thing I want to mention, I read about "Services" and it the right way. But I did it in other simple way.

I have two activities (1) Bluetooth search activity, and (2) Direction activity.

My problem was that I tried to do all the Bluetooth stuuf in activity (1) and just send command from activity (2) to (1) which will send it to the RC Car. And this is problem because as @Mackovich said the activity may be **destroyed**.

What did I do to solve is?
In activity (1) I used a ListView to display the Bluetooth devices broadcasting and to get these devices info. Then use an **Intent** to pass these info to the activity (2). Instated of connecting and trying to send in activity (1).

**Note:** In order to make a Bluetooth connection you need two important information:

1. UUID (which we aleard have).

2. MAC Address of the targeted Bluetooth device. (Which we get it form activity(1)).

So, first we need Bluetooth Adapter, Array Adapter (To holed the info of devices found) and Broadcast Receiver.

```
//Declare Bluetooth Stuff
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter; // Make instance of the Bluetooth
    ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter; // Array where the devices will be stored
    private static final int ENABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    private static final int DISCOVERABLE_DURATION = 300;
    public static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "Device_MAC_Address";

    //In order for the bluetooth to discover the devices that broadcasting and obtain their info.
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // Whenever a remote Bluetooth device is found
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                mArrayAdapter.add(mBluetoothDevice.getName() + "\n" + mBluetoothDevice.getAddress());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Paired Bluetooth Devices Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

Then, after the user select one of the devices listed. We will obtain the device MAC address and send it to activity (2) to connect and send.

```
//Obtain the value of the item clicked as String value
                String itemValue = (String) DevicesList.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //Extract the MAC Address from the String value above
                String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);
                // Make an intent to start next activity.
                Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothActivity.this, NavigationActivity.class);
                //Change the activity.
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, MAC); //this will be received at  NavigationActivity(class) Activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Now, We solved the problem of passing data between activities. Because there is no need foe passing data.

This was for the Problem (1) in original post.

As for problem (2). 
The problem is if you used the code provided by Google. There is things you need to adjust. In the class `ConnectThread` insaid `run` method you need to define the object of the class `ConnectedThread` you created. By this way you will pass the `BluetoothSocket` variable used to connect to send data throw it.

And that also solves problem (3). And yes you need the two classes.

As I said in the Original Post I am beginner. So, I figured that what is the best way to explain to beginners is to think like one. Which in this case I am actually beginner.

I hope this is going to help someone else. And PLEASE if some find any thing in this is wrong. PLEASE tell me to correct it.

Thank you.