# Passing variables using intents - Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently developing an android application that makes use of Google Places API.

I have 2 activities that I want to pass a variable between. I have tried passing by Intent using putExtras and getExtras.

I have been having issues with the getExtras. I have debugged my code, used breakpoints and an output of the variable to the log.

Here is my code for the activity of which I want to pass the variable from:

```
   Intent mapIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MapsActivity.class);

   Spinner distanceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_distance);

   String radius = distanceSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

   mapIntent.putExtra("radius", radius);

   Log.e("Passer", String.valueOf(radius)); //Shows that value is not = null.

   startActivity(mapIntent);
```

The log out put for this class is correct and displays the variable.

Here is the code for my class that I want to pass the variable to:

```
Intent filterIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LocateFilterActivity.class);

Bundle bd = filterIntent.getExtras();
String radius= (String) bd.get("radius");

Log.e("TESTER", String.valueOf(radius));

startActivity(placeIntent);
```

The log does not actually output anything for this class. I know it can reach and execute the line of code through debugging.

I have tried coding this several different ways following previous SO questions/answers but not having much luck.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you are trying to access wrong intent data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using intents to pass data between activities in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286970/using-intents-to-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: try `getIntent().getStringExtra("radius");` in your `LocateFilterActivity` activity `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can access data which were passed to an activity with getIntent().getExtras() method which you can call in a newly created activity that you have created with startActivity(intent) call. :)