# Android how to use get set method for image?

Tags: android, image

In my android application i have one image . i want to change that image using get set methods. I have tried but nothing displayed on the image.

My Method class is ..

```
int image;

 public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.imo = image;
    }
```

My activity class 1 is ..

```
public class activity1 extends AppCompatActivity{
    Method m=new Method;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.song_list);

     cc.setImage(R.drawable.album8);
    }
}
```

My activity Class 2 is

```
public class activity2 extends AppCompatActivity{


    Method aa=new Method;

      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.song_list);

        ImageView ss= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.songimage);



        ss.setImageResource(aa.getImage());

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User yout "Method" class like this :

public class Method {

```
private static Method instance;
private int image;

public static synchronized Method getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new Method();
    }

    return instance;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}
After on your Activitys :

Method.getInstance().getImage();
Method.getInstance().setImage();

Answer (score 1):

User yout "Method" class like this :

```
public class Method {

    private static Method instance;
    private int image;

    public static synchronized Method getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Method();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

After on your Activitys :

```
Method.getInstance().getImage();
Method.getInstance().setImage();
```

Problem with your code : The model instance lost when you open the other activity.

Ps :

That would be a better way, if you pass your image via intent. 
Link : [Using intents to pass data between activities in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286970/using-intents-to-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

At this point the question is rather vague, could be a few different things.

Could you provide the contents of R.layout.song_list? And at what point are you starting activity2?