# broadcastreceiver intent launch activity other application notification

Tags: java, android

I create 2 app (appA, appB) , from appA i send message to appB, in appB a catch this message and create notification , but i want on i click notification open my appA and see my message.

appA

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView text;
Button send;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    View.OnClickListener Onlistbtn = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("com.example.abc.send_messege.broadcast.Message",text.getText().toString());
            intent.setAction("com.example.abc.send_messege.custom_action");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    };

    send.setOnClickListener(Onlistbtn);
}}
```

appB

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private final static AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(3);
public MyReceiver() {
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String text = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.abc.send_messege.broadcast.Message");
    //Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(getID(), mBuilder.build());


}
public static int getID() {
    return c.incrementAndGet();
}}
```

AndroidManifest appB

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.abc.send_messege.custom_action" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you can try this

We you are creating the PendingIntent pass the new intent to [launch activity from another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209513/how-to-start-activity-in-another-application)(appA)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

//com.colisa.broadcast is the package of another app
//com.colisa.broadcast.MainActivity is the actity to be launched
intent.setComponent(
   new ComponentName("com.colisa.broadcast","com.colisa.broadcast.MainActivity"));
```

Then you will pass it to the `PengingIntent.setContentIntent(intent)`

I haven't triend this but i think you can `intent.putExtra(key, message)` and on receiving Activity get that messsage via ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286970/using-intents-to-pass-data-between-activities-in-android))

```
if (null != getIntent().getExtras().getString(key)){
  // whatever
}
```

Comment: thank you , but why i can use old intent from appA in appB and need create new intent? I try add ComponentName in appA and send appB but it dont work ...

Comment: are you getting any kind of error? you can use `Intent.setFlag(FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION)` for extra log information about intent resolution

Comment: no but if i try use old intent (appA) broadcastreceiver can't get my messege in appB