# Not able to clear shred preferences

Tags: android

This is in my main activity class, I can pass and retrieve data in my other class through shared preferences but I cant clear the shared preferences in my other class. Also tell me how to check that my shared preferences are cleared.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Name = "userKey";
public static final String Pass = "passKey";

 sharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(Name,userName);
                    editor.putString(Pass,password);
                    editor.commit();
```

this is in my other class

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    sharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SignUPActivity.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
```

Comment: The name of the SharedPreferences is not one. so not able to clear shred preferences. please check the file name first.

Comment: Remove _editor.apply();_. You have already called _editor.commit();_

Comment: i have changed the name and removed editor.apply();

Answer (score 0):

Possible Reason is you are not using the same preferences.

In your first activity you are using:

```
sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And in the other activity you should also use it.

Try to read these 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

also from the docs

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are
>   private to this activity. This simply calls the underlying
>   getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's
>   class name as the preferences name.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want just pass value from one Activity to Another or One Fragment to other than I suggest you to use **INTENT**  to pass data

Look at this example how to pass -http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/241-lesson-28-extras-passing-data-using-intent.html

Also -https://stackoverflow.com/a/30166602/4741746

**sharedPreferences** is used when data used for all activity which is permanatly stored in application you also can clear data

Remove given String from shearedPrefrance

```
public static void removeFromSharedPreferences(Context mContext, String key) {
    if (mContext != null) {
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
        if (mSharedPreferences != null)
            mSharedPreferences.edit().remove(key).commit();
    }
}
```

Remove All value from SharedPrefrance

```
public static void removeSharedPreferences(Context mContext) {
    if (mContext != null) {
       SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.clear(); 
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

And why your code is not working is you have to passs **Context.MODE_PRIVATE insted MODE_PRIVATE** jsut confirm both should have same value

Put this code in both the classes

```
 SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Comment: Still not Working

Comment: SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);            use this to getShearedPrefrance in both the classes

Comment: Problem remains

Comment: surly you are doing it wrong way  - just double check it and use intent instead of shearedPrefrance

Comment: I know i am doing it the worong but i don't know that where i am wrong