# Android Studio passing data

Tags: android-studio

I created a layout without activity in an android studio, so I want to pass to this layout in mainActivity, how can I do this?
mean that using Intent or something like that to pass to other layouts without Activity or java class.

Comment: use shared preferences or search for passing the data from one intent to another on google you will find many of them.

Comment: please share the code you've written so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using intents to pass data between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286970/using-intents-to-pass-data-between-activities)

Comment: Show us what you have done. I am interested in how to 'create a layout without activity', and why you want to 'pass this layout to mainActivity'.