# Android | Cannot receive Intent Key in my second activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hi I've been trying to get this to work in my game but it won't work. I can get lives key to reappear in the second activity but the gold key won't work.
Here is my first activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EndActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("lives", lives);
                        intent.putExtra("gold", gold);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

My 2nd Activity

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
    int gold = extras.getExtras().getInt("gold", 0);
    int lives = extras.getExtras().getInt("lives", 0);
```

am i missing anything? I've check my spelling. I tried to see if only 1 key is allowed in Intent. I've checked other questions but I can't find any that helps.

Comment: What is the output?? Or any errors??

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649728/android-cannot-pass-intent-extras-though-alarmmanager/18649849#18649849

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,be sure that lives and gold are int when you do this:

```
intent.putExtra("lives", lives); intent.putExtra("gold", gold);
```

Second,you have to use this code in second Activity:

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

```
if (extras.containsKey("lives") && extras.containsKey("lives") )
{
 int gold = extras.getExtras().getInt("gold";
 int lives = extras.getExtras().getInt("lives");
}
```

Also, pay attention on this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,EndActivity.class);
```

So you have to use FirstActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext();

Comment: aaaaaaaaa im soo stupid!!! I had gold as long!!! I turned it into int and its all fine now! I had to remake my app after it got deleted and it worked in previous version! I guess I changed it to int then but forgot about it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
int gold = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("gold"));
```

or

```
int gold = extras.getInt("gold");
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
 Intent i = new Intent(first.this, EndActivity.class);
           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           bundle.putInt("gold", gold);
           bundle.putInt("gold", gold);
           i.putExtras(bundle);
           startActivity(i);
```

end activity :

```
Bundle getData = getIntent().getExtras();
        int gold = getData.getInt("gold");
         int lives = getData.getInt("lives");
```