# ArrayList contains null after being passed to next activity

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, bundle

I use an `ArrayList` to store some data and then pass it to the next activity where it is actually required through the `.putStringArrayList()` method. I use the same process in a couple of places in a my project where it works absolutely fine. However, in this particular case, when I extract it in the receiving activity, it contains `null`. To be sure, I even displayed the list before sending it, and it did displayed the strings I require. Here is my code for sending the Arraylist:

```
 for(int i=0; i<AssignmentTitles.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(AssignmentTitles.get(i));

        }
        Intent localIntent;
        localIntent = new Intent(CourseFolder.this, Assignments.class);
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putStringArrayList("titles",AnnouncementTitles);
        b.putStringArrayList("links",AnnouncementLinks);
        localIntent.putExtras(b);

        startActivity(localIntent);
```

Here is the receiving activity code:

```
    AssignmentTitles = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("titles");
    AssignmentLinks = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("links");
    System.out.println("size: " + AssignmentLinks.size() + "TITLES:");
    for(int i=0; i<AssignmentTitles.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(AssignmentTitles.get(i));

    }
    setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String(Assignments.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    AssignmentTitles));
```

The problem is that I use the exact same code in another part of my project and it works perfectly, what could be the problem?

Comment: Ok I can see you have printed the ArrayList of AssignmentTitles but sending AnnouncementTitles. Is that correct ?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649728/android-cannot-pass-intent-extras-though-alarmmanager/18649849#18649849

Comment: @Jibran I love you. Such a stupid mistake, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
AssignmentTitles = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("titles");
        AssignmentTitles = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("links");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent.getExtras()` to get the `Bundle` first, then extract your array lists.