# Android: How to get the Bundle in an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am programming Android now;
A bundle could be saved in an intent by method putExtra().
This intent could be further specified by which Activity it will start. And used by startActivity(Intent); how can I then retrieve the Bundle in the Intent in the new activity? Will the bundle automatically match the intent reference in method onCreate(Bundle) of the new activity?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649728/android-cannot-pass-intent-extras-though-alarmmanager/18649849#18649849

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use getIntent() to retrieve the intent used to create the activity and you can then use getExtra on the intent.