# How To give notifications on android on specific time?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to give notification to my app on a specific time. Say everyday i have to give notification on 7 AM even if the app is closed.

How can i do this? Any tutorial?
Please mention the link.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First you need to use a [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver), and because a broadcast receiver can only run for a short time, it's a better practice to use an intent service, here you have an example how to do it.

> When handling a broadcast, the application is given a fixed set of time (currently 10 seconds) in which to do its work. If it doesn't complete in that time, the application is considered to be misbehaving, and its process immediately tossed into the background state to be killed for memory if needed.
>
> (from the android developer blog)

This is the broadcast receiver class:

```java
    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public MyReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyNewIntentService.class);
            context.startService(intent1);
        }
    }
```

Register it in the manifest:

```xml
    <receiver
        android: name=".MyReceiver"
        android: enabled="true"
        android: exported="false" >
    </receiver>
```

This is the intent service class:

```java
    public class MyNewIntentService extends IntentService {
        private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 3;

        public MyNewIntentService() {
            super("MyNewIntentService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
                builder.setContentTitle("My Title");
                builder.setContentText("This is the Body");
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.whatever);
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            //to be able to launch your activity from the notification 
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            Notification notificationCompat = builder.build();
            NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            managerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationCompat);
        }
    }
```

Register it in the manifest:

```xml
    <service
        android: name=".MyNewIntentService"
        android: exported="false" >
    </service>
```

Then in your activity, set the alarm manager to start the broadcast receiver at a specific time and use AlarmManager's `setRepeating` method to repeat it. In the example below, it will repeat it every day:

```java
    
     Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this,MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (context, NOTIFICATION_REMINDER_NIGHT, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  System.currentTimeMillis(),
                1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Not working for me, tried with manually set time but still wont work.

Comment: Any reason for using Broadcasts? Don't see this as being necessary/useful. You could directly talk to your IntentService with a PendingIntent.

Comment: Will it work in Pie version? Doesn't seem to do so :(

Comment: @NarendraSingh That's because you need a notification channel for android O and higher. See https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Priority

Comment: Use the Google Sample for Alarm System based Notifications
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-kotlin-notifications

Comment: @SriKrishna Hey, I have a notification issue would appreciate your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76949162/scheduled-notification-not-appearing-andriod-13

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite the answer for the current andriodX platform for andriod 13

Answer (score 17):

You can use `AlarmManager` to set alarm at specified time

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
    editor.apply();
}
```

I used `SharedPreferences` to check that's not the first time to run the app and if it is, you set that alarm otherwise do nothing instead of resetting the alarm each time you start your app.
Use a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen when the alarm happens

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // show toast
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Use another receiver to listen to device boots so that you can reset the alarm

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // on device boot compelete, reset the alarm
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

add the permission to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

then register your receivers

```
<receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

Comment: What if it's to send notification when opening the app also?

Comment: You can add the notification code in `onCreate()` method of your launcher activity.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would the `SharedPReference` work for the next day? Because the boolean will be false

Comment: You're welcome. `SharedPreferences` is supposed to work only once in case of first start of the app to set the alarm, then it sets the boolean to true i.e. app started before, to avoid resetting alarm over and over.

Comment: So the next day, the alarm will go off again at the time?

Comment: I actually thought abt it and you are right, What I was originally doing was in the Activity, checking the value and keep setting the alarm everytime. Since I am doing `setRepeating()` then I set it once and never have to set it again, unless I want to clear the alarm from pushing a notification. Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah it's ok, alarm is set always unless device booted or you stopped it.

Comment: In a case for device booted, the code you provided should take care of it? Can you please post a sample for the `AlarmReceiver` function to send notification at the time defined?

Comment: I have `DeviceBootReceiver` that resets the alarm when device boots because device boot removes the alarm. Both codes in receiver and activity set the alarm at a defined time.

Comment: You may need to put a flag if your intents magically disappear: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28203623/334493). Also, your `Serializable` objects may get null if they're not wrapped in a `Bundle`: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40515978/334493).

Comment: @SaNtoRiaN Hey, I have a notification issue would appreciate your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76949162/scheduled-notification-not-appearing-andriod-13

Answer (score 16):

A solution from the accepted answer will not work properly on **Android 8 Oreo (api level 26) and higher** due to background service limits (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services) and will cause an exception like this when the app is in background:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent xxx: app is in background
```

One of the possible workarounds is using [`JobIntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html):

1. extend your `Service` from `JobIntentService` instead of `IntentService` and use `onHandleWork` method instead of `onHandleIntent`.
2. add `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"` to your `Service` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: this method isn't working while using the code given in Accepted Answer and modify it according to your instructions. It's not calling `BroadCastReceiver`. How may I solve that?

Comment: It's quite difficult to say without seeing your code. If you have a problem with receiver, it happens before starting a service, I mean no matter you use my suggestion or from the accepter answer. Have you registered your receiver in manifest?

Comment: Why not leave out the Service alltogether? Setting up a notification should be fast enough to be done in the BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my **solution**, tested on **android 10** but compatible with all the previous versions of android.

**MainActivity.class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    reminderNotification();

}

public void reminderNotification()
{
    NotificationUtils _notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(this);
    long _currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long tenSeconds = 1000 * 10;
    long _triggerReminder = _currentTime + tenSeconds; //triggers a reminder after 10 seconds.
    _notificationUtils.setReminder(_triggerReminder);
}
```

**NotificationUtils.class**

```
public class NotificationUtils extends ContextWrapper
{

    private NotificationManager _notificationManager;
    private Context _context;

    public NotificationUtils(Context base)
    {
        super(base);
        _context = base;
        createChannel();
    }

    public NotificationCompat.Builder setNotification(String title, String body)
    {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    }

    private void createChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, TIMELINE_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    public NotificationManager getManager()
    {
        if(_notificationManager == null)
        {
            _notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }

        return _notificationManager;
    }

    public void setReminder(long timeInMillis)
    {
        Intent _intent = new Intent(_context, ReminderBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent _pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_context, 0, _intent, 0);

        AlarmManager _alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        _alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, _pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

**ReminderBroadcast.class**

```
public class ReminderBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        NotificationUtils _notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder _builder = _notificationUtils.setNotification("Testing", "Testing notification system");
        _notificationUtils.getManager().notify(101, _builder.build());
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>
    ...
    <receiver android:name=".custom.ReminderBroadcast"/>
</application>
```

NB: **`CHANNEL_ID`** and **`TIMELINE_CHANNEL_NAME`**, have been created on another class.

For example,

`CHANNEL_ID = "notification channel"`;

`TIMELINE_CHANNEL_NAME = "Timeline notification"`;

If there are any misconceptions about my code and bugs, don't hesitate to comment. I will reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Unable to see Notifications in my System Notifications Area. No Crash. No Notification.

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite the answer for the current andriodX platform for andriod 13

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @SriKrishna & others. Currently, I have immersed my mobile development on flutter I no longer do native development. Thanks, for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

- Get the Alarm service from the system.
- Make a pending intent, passing in the broadcast receiver class's name.
- Make a calendar object and set the time of it too 8 am.
- Check if the current time is past 8. If yes then add another day to it.
- Call the set repeating method of AlarmManager class.

Sample code for the same:

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);   
alarmIntent = new Intent(context of current file, AlarmReceiver1.class); 
AlarmReceiver1 = broadcast receiver

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  Menu.this, 0, alarmIntent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmIntent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if (now.after(alarmStartTime)) {
        Log.d("Hey","Added a day");
        alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

     alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
     Log.d("Alarm","Alarms set for everyday 8 am.");
```

Coming to the broadcast receiver class. You need to register your broadcast receiver in the manifest. This will cause you to receive clock events.
Override the onReceive method of this broadcast receiver and make a notification there itself or make a seperate notification building service and build and display your notification there.

The manifest code snippet:

The broadcast receiver code snippet:

```
public class AlarmReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotificationService1.class);
service1.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
          context.startService(service1);
}
```

Notification building service code snippet:

```
public class NotificationService1 extends IntentService{

private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
Notification notification;
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
       notificationManager = 
(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Activity to be opened after clicking on the 
notif);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
        bundle.putString("test", "test");
        mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     

        Resources res = this.getResources();
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setTicker("ticker value")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(8)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setContentTitle("Notif title")
                    .setContentText("Text").build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.ledARGB = 0xFFFFA500;
        notification.ledOnMS = 800;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        Log.i("notif","Notifications sent.");

}

}
```

Comment: Hey, I have a notification issue would appreciate your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76949162/scheduled-notification-not-appearing-andriod-13

Answer (score 1):

Use NotifyMe Android Library for simple notifications. Very easily set a delay or time when you want the notification to popup. Notification will popup through system reboots.

Download library with Jitpack.io
Add this to your build.gradle file for your app.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Add this to your dependencies in build.gradle for your project.

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.jakebonk:NotifyMe:1.0.1'
}
```

Example
Create a NotifyMe Builder Object

```
NotifyMe.Builder notifyMe = new NotifyMe.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

Then set the fields you want.

```
notifyMe.title(String title);
notifyMe.content(String content);
notifyMe.color(Int red,Int green,Int blue,Int alpha);//Color of notification header
notifyMe.led_color(Int red,Int green,Int blue,Int alpha);//Color of LED when 
notification pops up
notifyMe.time(Calendar time);//The time to popup notification
notifyMe.delay(Int delay);//Delay in ms
notifyMe.large_icon(Int resource);//Icon resource by ID
notifyMe.rrule("FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5;COUNT=2")//RRULE for frequency of 
//notification
notifyMe.addAction(Intent intent,String text); //The action will call the intent when 
//pressed
```

After all the fields that you want are set just call build()!

```
notifyMe.build();
```