# Notification at Specific Time using BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to send notification at specific time using broadcast receiver. many tutorials videos and also answers has been read in this regard and all of them was clear. but I couldn't  find where is the problem of below codes because CODE still does not work.
all of this was implemented based on ***"Daily Repeating Local Notification In Android - YouTube"***

**Here is the CODE within LAUNCHER Activity:**

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    NotificationCheckPoint();

}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private void NotificationCheckPoint() {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 53);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent MyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BroadastNotification.class);
    PendingIntent MyPendIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100,
            MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager MyAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    MyAlarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, MyPendIntent);
       }
}
```

**and this is the BroadcastReceiver CODE:**

```
public class BroadastNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
MyNotification(context);
}
 private void MyNotification(Context context) {
 String BigNotificqationText = "BigNotificqationText";
 String NotificationTitle = "NotificationTitle";
 String NotificationTicker = " NotificationTicker ";

 NotificationManager MyNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 Intent MyIntent = new Intent(context, Splash.class);
 MyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

 PendingIntent MyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, MyIntent,
         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 NotificationCompat.Builder MyNB = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
 MyNB.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
 MyNB.setContentTitle(NotificationTitle);
 MyNB.setContentText(BigNotificqationText);
 MyNB.setTicker(NotificationTicker);
 MyNB.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
 MyNB.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
 MyNB.setAutoCancel(true);
 MyNB.setContentIntent(MyPendingIntent);

 Bitmap MyPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
 MyNB.setLargeIcon(MyPicture);

 NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle MyPicStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(MyPicture);
 MyPicStyle.setSummaryText("Etude can makes our life Enlightened");
 MyNB.setStyle(MyPicStyle);

 NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle MyTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();

 MyTextStyle.bigText(BigNotificqationText);
 MyTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(NotificationTitle);
 MyNB.setStyle(MyTextStyle);


 MyNotifyManager.notify(100, MyNB.build());

 }
```

**at the end it's the manifest definition:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.ietude.etude">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="icon, label">

    <receiver android:name=".BroadastNotification">
        <!--android:enabled="true"-->
        <!--android:exported="true">-->
        <!--<intent-filter>-->
            <!--<action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />-->
        <!--</intent-filter>-->
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: When you run this code what happens? Does onReceive() get called?

Comment: I tested it by putting a Toast Message, it seems onReceive() didn't call, but when I add intent action for receiver in manifest (VOLUMECONTROLCHANGED for example) broadcast was called when volume is changed.

Comment: And to confirm - you waited until after 19:53 had passed?

Comment: yes, defiantly, I changed it may time and wait to passed the time, but it seems there is a problem that I can not find it. also I tested it by Huawei and also Samsung Device, the result was same

Comment: Can you update the question to include the full manifest and the full class for the broadcast receiver?

Comment: it was updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to have a timer expire at an exact time, then you can configure the timer as follows.

```
Calendar alarmFor = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmFor.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
alarmFor.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
alarmFor.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Intent MyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BroadcastNotification.class);
PendingIntent MyPendIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager MyAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
MyAlarm.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmFor.getTimeInMillis(), MyPendIntent);
```

In this example, onReceive() is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("MyAPP", "onReceive() called");
}
```

When I run this, the following is logged at the the exact time requested:

```
11-22 07:45:00.730 5833-5833/com.sap.myapplication D/MyAPP: onReceive() called
```

Comment: really thanks dear Paul, I just copy and paste your CODE letter by letter  and disabled extra codes related to my app, but I didn't receive your test result. I really confused. what's going on to my app.

Comment: the only difference between my code and yours is `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)`. do you think it is change my result?, when I use `Calendar` , it gives an error and needs Api

Comment: I did not need to use @RequiresApi and received no errors. Please check your imports: are you using android.icu.util.Calendar? Please note that in my example I used java.util.Calendar.

Comment: It was solved finally, problem was that exactly, I import `java.util.Calendar` and everything became OK, really thanks for your kindly support dear Paul.

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy to hear it works for you now.

Comment: Here is the latest answer, tested on Android 10. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67812298/9942927

Answer (score 1):

The problem was detected, as I searched again in this regard I found that when Calendar has been set for 10 Second `calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);`it means BroadcastReceiver() must trigger Notification after 10 Second. it doesn't care the time of day. 
question still exist, **how we can tell broadcastreceiver() to Show Notification based on the time of day that we defined in the CODE exactly?** such as 16:33:24 (hh:mm:ss)

Answer (score 1):

You can send notification at specific time daily by following method

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
         calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
         calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),showNotification.class);
       notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(etApplicationContext(),0,notifyIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

Then in showNotification class

```
public class showNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

public showNotification() {

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   sendNotification(context);
}

private void sendNotification(Context context) {


    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "101";

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

        //Configure Notification Channel
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Game Notifications");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{200});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle(title.get("Title of notification"))
            .setContentText(subText.get("Sub text of notification"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);


    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

}

Comment: Don't forget to record the receiver to your manifest file:
 <receiver android:name=".ShowNotification"  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>