# NotificationCompat at a time

Tags: android, notifications

I want to show notification at defined time. I use "setWhen()". But any argument of setWhen() is ignoring and notification always showing instantly. What I did wrong? My code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setWhen(???)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Test")
                    .setContentText("Test");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: take a look to my question and the answer. I fixed it today. [Notification at Specific Time using BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420667/notification-at-specific-time-using-broadcastreceiver-and-alarmmanager)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the purpose of `setWhen`. It's only a UI thing, if `setShowWhen` is enabled this timestamp is **shown** at the notification.

For your purpose, I would suggest the android `AlarmManager`. An example can be found [here](http://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/)

Answer (score 1):

`setWhen()` is used to show the time on the notification itself, not when the notification is shown.

The time on the top right of the notification is what `setWhen()` controls:

[image]

For showing the notification at a particular time, you can use the `AlarmManager` class. [This](https://gist.github.com/BrandonSmith/6679223) has code to do the same.