# Is there any way to show notification when the app is killed or in background by using Notification Compat Builder in android?

Tags: android, mobile, android-notifications

I want to show the notification in mobile, when my app is killed or in background by using Notification Compat Builder in android. Any Suggestions or help are really appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the solution is here: [Notification at Specific Time using BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420667/notification-at-specific-time-using-broadcastreceiver-and-alarmmanager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) library. The workflow would be like this:

1. Create a `BroadcastReceiver`
2. Create an alarm at specific time in your code that has as an intent your `BroadcastReceiver`
3. On the `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive` method build your notification.