# Notification at specific time with time from sharedpreferences

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, checkboxpreference

I'm making an app where I want the user to specify a time in shared preferences then I'll use that time to launch a notification whether they're in the app or not, like a `user-defined alarm notification`.

I've tried everything but I don't know how to make it work. The notification should appear every day at that specific time if the preference (checkbox) is true.

Comment: http://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To give notifications on android on specific time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517520/how-to-give-notifications-on-android-on-specific-time)

Comment: Thanks Adeel Turk...Im checking out your answer right now and it seems like what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out how to do it. For anyone who might need the same, I'll post the code:

This here is the method to call the notification in the activity once time is right:

```
 public void notifyAtTime() {
    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    long time = sharedPref.getLong("Timepref", 0);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH", Locale.UK);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm", Locale.UK);

    Date date = new Date(time);
    Date date1 = new Date(time);
    long hour = Long.parseLong(formatter.format(date));
    long minute = Long.parseLong(formatter1.format(date1));

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) minute);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, broadcast);
    }
}
```

This here is the receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TicketActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(TicketActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String ringer = sharedPreferences.getString("key_notifications_new_message_ringtone","");
    boolean vibrate = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Vibrate",true);
    Uri ringtone = Uri.parse(ringer);

    Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notific))
            .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notific))
            .setTicker(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notific))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setSound(ringtone)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set Remainder in Preferences

```
    public static void setReminder(Context context,Class<?> cls,int hour, int min) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar setcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        // cancel already scheduled reminders
        cancelReminder(context,cls);

        if(setcalendar.before(calendar))
            setcalendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);

        // Enable a receiver
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, cls);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, cls);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
                                     DAILY_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE, intent1,           
                                      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,setcalendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
 }
```

Trigger Ala-ram

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Trigger the notification
        NotificationScheduler.showNotification(context, MainActivity.class,
                "You have 5 unwatched videos", "Watch them now?");
    }
}
```

Show Notification

```
public static void showNotification(Context context,Class<?> cls,String title,String content)
    {
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, cls);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(cls);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                     DAILY_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content).setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(alarmSound).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(DAILY_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE, notification);
    }
```

Show Time Picker Dialog.

```
private void showTimePickerDialog(int h, int m) 
 {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timepicker_header, null);

    TimePickerDialog builder = new TimePickerDialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme,
             new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
             @Override
             public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int min) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "onTimeSet: hour " + hour);
                   Log.d(TAG, "onTimeSet: min " + min);
                   localData.set_hour(hour);
                   localData.set_min(min);
                   tvTime.setText(getFormatedTime(hour,min));
                   NotificationScheduler.setReminder(MainActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class,
                                                     localData.get_hour(),localData.get_min());
                }
            }, h, m, false);
        builder.setCustomTitle(view);
        builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: just saw your answer..looks promising but one thing,where do i set the user specified time.im using a custom timepicker to allow the user to set time

Comment: I have edited answer please check Show Time Picker Dialog. method to set the specific time.

Comment: Ok i think you didnt get my question...well I have a prefrences activity where i have a time picker and a couple of checkboxes to switch on or off the ability to receive notifications,whether to vibrate or not and the notification sound.I have all those figured out except for the part where after selecting a time for the notification from the timepicker.This time should be added as the trigger time for the alarm.