# Store ArrayList<PendingIntent> into SharedPreferences

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, android-pendingintent

II couldn't find an answer for my problem so I decided to post a question. The question is simple.

How can I store an `ArrayList<PendingIntent>` into `SharedPreferences`? What is the best way, do i have to use some kind of `Serialization`?

Thank you in advance, any advice would be great!

Comment: I'm not sure storing pending intents in shared preferences is even feasible. May be it is better to restate the question on the higher level: what is it you need to store (in shared prefernces or elsewhere) which you want to use as pending intent?

Comment: you cant store PendingIntent or array of such objects to SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

`PendingIntent` is created with `getActivity()`, `getBroadcast()` or `getService()`. Each of these functions has the same list of parameters:

```
(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, @Flags int flags)
```

You cannot save `Context`, but you can save:

- Type of `PendingIntent` (i.e. `"Activity"`, `"Broadcast"` or `"Service"`)
- Request code and flags (integers)
- `Intent` (using its `toUri()` method that returns `String`)

Thus, you can save in `SharedPreferences` all data that represents your `PendingIntent`, excluding `Context` (but `Context` instance is always available in your application.). Then you can easily restore saved `PendingIntent` from this data (using `parseUri()` method for restoring `Intent`).

Answer (score 0):

`PendingIntent` implements `Parcelable`. You'll need to loop through your `ArrayList` and convert each `PendingIntent` into a `String`. You can then concatenate all the individual `String`s into a single `String` (with some delimiter in between each one). Then write the resulting `String` to `SharedPreferences`.

You can convert a `Parcelable` into a `byte[]` like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = // Your PendingIntent here
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain(); // Get a Parcel from the pool
pendingIntent.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
byte[] bytes = parcel.marshall();
parcel.recycle(); // Return the Parcel to the pool
```

Now convert the `byte[]` to a `String` by using base64 encoding (or any other mechanism, like converting each byte into 2 hexadecimal digits). To use base64 you can do this:

```
String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.NO_PADDING);
```

See [How to marshall and unmarshall a Parcelable to a byte array with help of Parcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000093/how-to-marshall-and-unmarshall-a-parcelable-to-a-byte-array-with-help-of-parcel) for more information about how to convert a `Parcelable` to `byte[]` and vice-versa.

Answer (score -2):

From [AndroidSolution4u](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/02/store-arraylist-in-android.html)

```
//suppos you have already an arraylist like this

ArrayList<String> myArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
myArrayList.add("value1");
myArrayList.add("value2");
myArrayList.add("value3");
myArrayList.add("value4");
myArrayList.add("value5");
myArrayList.add("value6");
```

**Store arraylist in sharedpreference**

```
SharedPreference sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreference.Editor sEdit=sPrefs.edit();

for(int i=0;i<myArrayList.size();i++)
{
     sEdit.putString("val"+i,myArrayList.get(i);
}
sEdit.putInt("size",myArrayList.size());
sEdit.commit();
```

**Retrive arraylist from sharedpreference**

I am retriving values in another arraylist

```
 ArrayList<String> myAList=new ArrayList<String>();
 int size=sPrefs.getInt("size",0);

 for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
 {
      myAList.add(sPrefs.getString("val"+j));
 }
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418160/store-and-retrieve-a-class-object-in-shared-preference) may help you.

Comment: But how should I save the PendingIntent object? For string I have the putString() method.