# Saving Pending-Intent into Shared Preferences in form of Array-list or anything?

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, android-pendingintent

i am working on an App in which i want to save the pending intent into shared preference and perform some action on app if that pending intent exist in shared preferences.

**Reference Link :**

[Store ArrayList<PendingIntent> into SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672035/store-arraylistpendingintent-into-sharedpreferences)

but no solution found in this link as well.

if someone know how can i do this then plz let me know.

**Thanks.**

Comment: I just added an answer to the linked question. That should help you.

Comment: Why do you want to save the `PendingIntent`s to `SharedPreferences`? I doubt that this is the correct solution to whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the solution. i you have multiples alarms and you want to cancel few of them.then i think we can cancel only through its pending intent. that is the reason why i am saving pending intent. is my approach right for this ?

Comment: No this is the wrong approach. I've added an answer. If you post the code that you use to create the `PendingIntent` to set the alarms, I can edit my code to match yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote in a comment:

> If you have multiple alarms and you want to cancel a few of them, then I
>   think we can cancel only through its `PendingIntent`. That is the
>   reason why I am saving `PendingIntent`. Is my approach right for this?

No. This isn't the right approach to solve this problem.

Yes, you'll need to provide a `PendingIntent` to `AlarmManager.cancel()`. However, you don't need to save the `PendingIntent` in a persistent store. What you need to do is to save enough information in the persistent store so that you can recreate the `PendingIntent`.

To recreate the `PendingIntent` you just do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.NO_CREATE);
if (pendingIntent != null) {
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); // cancel alarm
    pendingIntent.cancel(); // delete the PendingIntent
}
```

I've used an `Activity` in the example code, but you can also use a `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver`, whatever you are using in your code.

You **do NOT need** to add any extras to the `Intent` if you just want to use it to cancel an existing alarm.

If you have multiple alarms, the `Intent`s **must be unique**. You just need to save whatever you are using to make them unique (`requestCode`, or `Intent` ACTION, or whatever) and then use the same parameters to recreate the `PendingIntent` when you want to cancel the alarms.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to bytes-array and back, by using this class I've made (found somewhere else) :

```
object PendingIntentUtil {
    @JvmStatic
    fun marshall(parcelable: Parcelable): ByteArray {
        val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
        parcelable.writeToParcel(parcel, 0)
        val bytes = parcel.marshall()
        parcel.recycle()
        return bytes
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun <T> unmarshall(bytes: ByteArray, creator: Parcelable.Creator<T>): T {
        val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
        parcel.unmarshall(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
        parcel.setDataPosition(0)
        val result = creator.createFromParcel(parcel)
        parcel.recycle()
        return result
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun marshallSerializable(serializable: Serializable): ByteArray? {
        val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val out: ObjectOutput
        try {
            out = ObjectOutputStream(bos)
            out.writeObject(serializable)
            out.flush()
            return bos.toByteArray()
        } catch (ignored: IOException) {
        } finally {
            closeQuietly(bos)
        }
        return null
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun <T> unmarshallSerializable(bytes: ByteArray?): T? {
        if (bytes == null) return null
        val bis = ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
        var objectInput: ObjectInput? = null
        try {
            objectInput = ObjectInputStream(bis)
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return objectInput.readObject() as T
        } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            closeQuietly(objectInput)
        }
        return null
    }
}
```