# parcelable object in appwidget provider always return null

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I am always getting **null**, when getting parcelable object from `RemoteViewsService` in `onReceive()` method of `AppWidgetProvider`.

I tried it, passing `string` and `int` and it worked perfectly but not incase of `parcelable`.

**StackWidgetProvider.java** extends AppWidgetProvider

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(INTENT_ACTION)){

            Artwork artwork = (Artwork) intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_ART);
            Log.e("Intent","->"+artwork.getTitle());
            Intent showArtDetail = new Intent(context, ArtsDetailsActivity.class);
            showArtDetail.putExtra(ArtsDetailsActivity.TAG_ARTWORK, artwork);
            showArtDetail.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(showArtDetail);
        }

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
```

**StackWidgetService.java** extends RemoteServiceView

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable(StackWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ART, artwork);

Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
remoteViews.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_item, fillInIntent);
```

Comment: If I had to guess, you are running into another place [where custom `Parcelable` implementations do not work](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare you solved my problem. Feel free to post it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom `Parcelable` class can only be used by processes that contain that class. Usually, that means the custom `Parcelable` class only works with an app's own process.

The corollary to this is that [there are many places where custom `Parcelable` implementations do not work](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html), because some *other* process tries working with the `Parcelable` and fails with a `ClassNotFoundException` (or the equivalent).

One such pattern is when you put a custom `Parcelable` as an extra in an `Intent` wrapped in a `PendingIntent`, and some other process wants to fill in that `Intent` with additional extras. Along the way, the other process will need access to the full `Bundle` of extras in the `Intent`, and that will fail because the other process lacks the custom `Parcelable`. In this case, the home screen would not have your custom `Parcelable`.

Either:

- Skip this custom `Parcelable` outright, or
- Skip the custom `Parcelable` but put some identifier in as an extra that will allow you to get that `Parcelable` back later on (e.g., from a cache or, if needed, reloaded from a data store), or
- Convert it into some other format first, such as [converting it to a `byte[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18000094/115145), before putting it in the extra