# Intent extras are lost with a broadcast PendingIntent and AlarmManager.setAlarmClock()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast, android-alarms

I create a `PendingIntent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("Foobar");
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ALARM, alarm);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TRYTWO, tryTwo);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_BEGAN_TIME, beganTime);

return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, (int) alarm.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

The `alarm` variable is a `Parcelable`. I schedule the `PendingIntent` like this:

```
PendingIntent alarmModifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 0, editIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
);

am.setAlarmClock(
    new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(time, alarmModifyPendingIntent), pendingIntent
);
```

Where the variable `pendingIntent` is created as shown above.

The `AlarmReceiver` object receives an `Intent` in `onReceive` at the correct time. However, this `Intent` does not contain the extras that I have set. For instance `intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_ALARM)` returns `null`.

This problem occurs with Android 7.0 (API level 24) at least, using an LG G5.

Using `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` or `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` does not work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The alarm variable is a Parcelable.

[It is not safe to put a custom `Parcelable` in an `Intent` that is delivered to another process](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html). This is particularly true with `AlarmManager` on Android 7.0.

You need to replace that `Parcelable` with something else, such as a `byte[]`, where [you manually convert your `Parcelable` to/from that `byte[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18000094/115145).

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I shall investigate.

Comment: I just tested it and you were indeed correct! Converting to byte[] works. Many thanks.

Comment: Online parcelable converters if used will no longer work if and until they convert the parcel to byte[].

Comment: @MatthewMitchell: Any time another process would need one of your classes, you'll have the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't it be considered a bug? Does Google warn about this anywhere? Does it have a support library class for helping handling this case? Does the Parcelable issue exist in other cases, other than AlarmManager ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "Shouldn't it be considered a bug?" -- no, IMHO. "Does Google warn about this anywhere?" -- not that I am aware of, outside of the comments on [the N issue I mentioned in my blog post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209422). "Does it have a support library class for helping handling this case?" -- no. "Does the Parcelable issue exist in other cases, other than AlarmManager ?" -- any time you pass a custom `Parcelable` outside of your process, the risk of this problem exists.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you provide example/s for passing a custom Parcelable outside of your process? Why don't you consider this a bug? It worked in previous versions, and it's quite a basic thing to be able to do...

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "Can you provide example/s for passing a custom Parcelable outside of your process?" -- convert them to/from `byte[]`. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Parcelable/Marshall). "Why don't you consider this a bug?" -- because any time you pass a custom `Parcelable` outside of your app, another app might try to read it in, and that's going to fail, because the other app does not have your class. In this case, the problem stems from `fillIn()` on `PendingIntent` IIRC. I try to stick to built-in types.

Comment: @CommonsWare I didn't mean provide a code. I mean to describe another case this occurs, other than AlarmManager. About the issue itself, according to this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209422#c3 , they say it will get updated in the docs, but I don't see the docs saying about this matter, and the issue is already closed...

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "I mean to describe another case this occurs, other than AlarmManager" -- any time you use a custom `Parcelable` in a `PendingIntent` that is filled in by another app. I seem to recall this happening with notifications. I would expect it to happen with the `PendingIntent` flavors of `LocationManager` methods. And so on. What changed is that `AlarmManager` never used to fill in a `PendingIntent`, and now it does.

Comment: @CommonsWare So is it at least safe to put byte array and primitive Java data there? Just not Parcealable ? What about Parcealable objects that are a part of Android framework (you wrote "custom" ones) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: What is causing the crash is that another process is trying to work with the extras in an `Intent`, and one of those is from a custom `Parcelable` class that the other process does not have. `Parcelable` classes that are in the zygote (i.e., classes in the framework, not from a library) are safe, as all Android SDK processes have the same definitions of those classes. Primitive data is also safe. However, `Serializable` will have the same problem as `Parcelable`, for the same reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare So the conclusion is to never put any Parcelable object into Pending intents, and only the primitive data are safe to use, right? Thanks.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Primitive data, platform-supplied `Parcelable`, platform-supplied `Serializable`, and arrays/lists of those should all be fine. If you need a custom `Parcelable` or `Serializable` subclass, the safest thing is to convert it to/from a `byte[]` yourself.

Comment: @CommonsWare What kind of platform-supplied Parcelable/Serializable ? Like PackageInfo for example? This will be safe to send there?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Sure. That is defined in the framework. Each Android SDK process has that class, and the same definition of that class to boot. `Bundle`, `Uri`, and lots of other `Parcelable` and `Serializable` classes will be safe. What is *not* safe is a *custom* one, where your app has the class, but apps (or system processes) that might work with your extras do not.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. I find this quite weird though. They could just pass it forward as normal intents with extras. No reason to mess with its content.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you.