# android - unable to pass parcelable in Intent to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, parcelable

hey i have an issue passing a parcelable POJO to a new activity. I have a listview which lists a bunch of news sources and it works fine. when i click on a item i am passing a parcelable object in the intent and expect in the "DetailsActivity" that the parcelable will be there but its null, any ideas ? i see the data being put into the intent successfully before i start the activity.  Here is some code:

The Result class is actually my parcelable pojo and looks like this:

```
    public class Result implements Parcelable
{

    @SerializedName("section")
    @Expose
    private String section;
    @SerializedName("subsection")
    @Expose
    private String subsection;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("abstract")
    @Expose
    private String _abstract;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("byline")
    @Expose
    private String byline;
    @SerializedName("item_type")
    @Expose
    private String itemType;
    @SerializedName("updated_date")
    @Expose
    private String updatedDate;
    @SerializedName("created_date")
    @Expose
    private String createdDate;
    @SerializedName("published_date")
    @Expose
    private String publishedDate;
    @SerializedName("material_type_facet")
    @Expose
    private String materialTypeFacet;
    @SerializedName("kicker")
    @Expose
    private String kicker;
    @SerializedName("des_facet")
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    private List<String> desFacet = null;
    @SerializedName("org_facet")
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    private String orgFacet;
    @SerializedName("per_facet")
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    private String perFacet;
    @SerializedName("geo_facet")
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    private List<String> geoFacet = null;
    @SerializedName("multimedia")
    @Expose
    private List<Multimedium> multimedia = null;
    public final static Parcelable.Creator<Result> CREATOR = new Creator<Result>() {


        @SuppressWarnings({
                "unchecked"
        })
        public Result createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            Result instance = new Result();
            instance.section = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.subsection = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.title = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance._abstract = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.url = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.byline = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.itemType = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.updatedDate = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.createdDate = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.publishedDate = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.materialTypeFacet = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.kicker = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            in.readList(instance.desFacet, (java.lang.String.class.getClassLoader()));
            instance.orgFacet = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.perFacet = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            in.readList(instance.geoFacet, (java.lang.String.class.getClassLoader()));
            in.readList(instance.multimedia, (Multimedium.class.getClassLoader()));
            return instance;
        }

        public Result[] newArray(int size) {
            return (new Result[size]);
        }

    }
            ;

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getSubsection() {
        return subsection;
    }

    public void setSubsection(String subsection) {
        this.subsection = subsection;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAbstract() {
        return _abstract;
    }

    public void setAbstract(String _abstract) {
        this._abstract = _abstract;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getByline() {
        return byline;
    }

    public void setByline(String byline) {
        this.byline = byline;
    }

    public String getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }

    public void setItemType(String itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }

    public String getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(String updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getPublishedDate() {
        return publishedDate;
    }

    public void setPublishedDate(String publishedDate) {
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }

    public String getMaterialTypeFacet() {
        return materialTypeFacet;
    }

    public void setMaterialTypeFacet(String materialTypeFacet) {
        this.materialTypeFacet = materialTypeFacet;
    }

    public String getKicker() {
        return kicker;
    }

    public void setKicker(String kicker) {
        this.kicker = kicker;
    }

    public List<String> getDesFacet() {
        return desFacet;
    }

    public void setDesFacet(List<String> desFacet) {
        this.desFacet = desFacet;
    }

    public String getOrgFacet() {
        return orgFacet;
    }

    public void setOrgFacet(String orgFacet) {
        this.orgFacet = orgFacet;
    }

    public String getPerFacet() {
        return perFacet;
    }

    public void setPerFacet(String perFacet) {
        this.perFacet = perFacet;
    }

    public List<String> getGeoFacet() {
        return geoFacet;
    }

    public void setGeoFacet(List<String> geoFacet) {
        this.geoFacet = geoFacet;
    }

    public List<Multimedium> getMultimedia() {
        return multimedia;
    }

    public void setMultimedia(List<Multimedium> multimedia) {
        this.multimedia = multimedia;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(section);
        dest.writeValue(subsection);
        dest.writeValue(title);
        dest.writeValue(_abstract);
        dest.writeValue(url);
        dest.writeValue(byline);
        dest.writeValue(itemType);
        dest.writeValue(updatedDate);
        dest.writeValue(createdDate);
        dest.writeValue(publishedDate);
        dest.writeValue(materialTypeFacet);
        dest.writeValue(kicker);
        dest.writeList(desFacet);
        dest.writeValue(orgFacet);
        dest.writeValue(perFacet);
        dest.writeList(geoFacet);
        dest.writeList(multimedia);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
```

and it uses another parcelable class which is called Multimedium:

```
 public class Multimedium implements Parcelable
{

    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("format")
    @Expose
    private String format;
    @SerializedName("height")
    @Expose
    private Integer height;
    @SerializedName("width")
    @Expose
    private Integer width;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("subtype")
    @Expose
    private String subtype;
    @SerializedName("caption")
    @Expose
    private String caption;
    @SerializedName("copyright")
    @Expose
    private String copyright;
    public final static Parcelable.Creator<Multimedium> CREATOR = new Creator<Multimedium>() {


        @SuppressWarnings({
            "unchecked"
        })
        public Multimedium createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            Multimedium instance = new Multimedium();
            instance.url = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.format = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.height = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.width = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.type = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.subtype = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.caption = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.copyright = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            return instance;
        }

        public Multimedium[] newArray(int size) {
            return (new Multimedium[size]);
        }

    }
    ;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    public Integer getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(Integer height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Integer getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(Integer width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getSubtype() {
        return subtype;
    }

    public void setSubtype(String subtype) {
        this.subtype = subtype;
    }

    public String getCaption() {
        return caption;
    }

    public void setCaption(String caption) {
        this.caption = caption;
    }

    public String getCopyright() {
        return copyright;
    }

    public void setCopyright(String copyright) {
        this.copyright = copyright;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(url);
        dest.writeValue(format);
        dest.writeValue(height);
        dest.writeValue(width);
        dest.writeValue(type);
        dest.writeValue(subtype);
        dest.writeValue(caption);
        dest.writeValue(copyright);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return  0;
    }
}
```

so in my Mainactivity i have the following method which looks fine in the debugger:

```
@Override
public void goToDetailsActivity(Result data) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("newsInfo", data);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

then when i go to the DetailViewActivity the program says the following is extra is null, but why ?

```
    public class DetailViewActivity extends Activity {
    private String storyURL = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        extras.getParcelable("newsInfo") //this is null , why ?

        getIntent().hasExtra("newsInfo") //this is also false ? why ?
//....
        }
```

Comment: Look for warnings in LogCat with stack traces. Also, are you sure that there is no existing instance of `DetailViewActivity`, perhaps without this extra, that is already in memory and is perhaps being reused (e.g., via `android:launchMode` in the manifest?). You might also temporarily switch to a plain extra (e.g., some boolean) and see if that makes it over, to help pin down if the problem is in your `Parcelable` implementation or if the problem covers all extras.

Comment: Passing a string works fine, just tried it. and there is nothing in the logs. the activity is defined like this in the manifest:   <activity android:name=".DetailViewActivity"/>

Comment: Well, if a string works, that suggests that there is a problem with the custom `Parcleable`, though I would expect a crash if that were the case. [Using custom `Parcelables` is dicey](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html), but passing between two of your own activities ought to be safe. Try using [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000093/how-to-marshall-and-unmarshall-a-parcelable-to-a-byte-array-with-help-of-parcel/18000094#18000094) to convert the `Parcelable` to a `byte[]`, see if you crash, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use this library: https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler

Comment: some how using this library resolved the issue. i was generating the parcelable from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and not sure what differences it has but thanks !