# Not ablet to pass Parcelable object as putExtra from IntentService to another Activity

Tags: android

Reivewed all the similar question, and yet no result.
I cannot pass one ojbect that implements parcelable from an intentService to an Activity. The Same code works fine when passing data from an activity to another activity. Even can pass ParcelableArrayListExtra also but not the parcelable Object. Its a requirment to pass the object in my project. 
Code is given below(Dont have right to publish whole code,and whole code is working except these lines)
CODE:
**IntentService:**

```
    Intent action = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("userList",name);
    Random position = new Random();
    int randomPosition =position.nextInt(3);
    intent.putExtra("selectedUser",name.get(randomPosition));
    action.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

SecondActivity:

```
List<User> userList= getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_INSECTS);
Insect selected = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("selectedUser");
```

Comment: Please explain **in detail** what "I cannot pass one ojbect that implements parcelable from an intentService to an Activity" means and what "but not the parcelable Object" means. What are your symptoms?

Comment: Do you receive exception?

Comment: Which api level do your test device use?

Comment: See i have to pass one list of 5 users in second activity and another user as extra from my IntentService to the Detail Activity.Both the arraylist of 5 users and one extra user object are there in intentservice. Now i m passing both. The array list by putParcelableArrayList and putExtra, retriving in the activity as shown in code. But nothing is recieved in the SELECTED named ojbect. It shows null object when i access it.

Comment: Are you made any model class(Pojo) ?

Comment: its on api level 26

Comment: what class(Pojo) means?

Comment: model class which have getter and setter method

Comment: Nope. See this same code works fine(without POJO) when i run it in one activity but doesnt work in intentService.PS:I'm not allowed to create POJO)

Comment: Then what is User ?

Answer (score 0):

I suposse that problem can be with putting a custom Parcelable on API 25+ from service to activity.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000093/how-to-marshall-and-unmarshall-a-parcelable-to-a-byte-array-with-help-of-parcel/18000094#18000094) has a workaround, in the form of converting the Parcelable yourself to/from a byte[].

Begin with passing single Parcelable object, not ArrayList.

```
    public static void putExtra(Intent intent, String key, Parcelable parcelable) {
    byte[] bytes = marshall(parcelable);
    intent.putExtra(key, bytes);
}
```

and

```
    public static <T> T getExtra(Intent intent, String key, Parcelable.Creator<T> creator) {
    byte[] bytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra(key);
    return ParcelableUtils.unmarshall(bytes, creator);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try below and when you get getParcelableArrayListExtra use same name.you have to implement User class with Parcelable.

```
Intent action = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("userList",name);
Random position = new Random();
int randomPosition =position.nextInt(3);
intent.putExtra("selectedUser",name.get(randomPosition));
action.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

> In SecondActivity :

```
ArrayList<User> userList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("userList");
for(User user : post){
    Log.d("user", user.getString());
}
```