# WakefulBroadcastReceiver is not working on Nougat and Oreo devices

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a alarm app which set alarm using Alarm Manager. Once the alarm goes off, it is received by the a receiver which starts the wakeful service which handle the alarm and allows user to stop or snooze the alarm.

below is the code snippet

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Alarm alarm = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.ARGS_ALARM);
    }
}
```

I am getting the proper value in older version of Android but getting alarm as null on Nougat and Oreo. My App support Nougat of minSdkVersion 17.

What could be wrong in this code?

Comment: where are you registering it ? `Manifest` ? If manifest please do check if it falls under [**`whitelist`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)  ...

Comment: Yes I am registering it in manifest like this   '<receiver android:name=".Receiver.AlarmReceiver" />' @SantanuSur

Comment: Did you add WAKE_LOCK permission?

Comment: Yes. Actually the same code is working in Lollipop devices @LeviAlbuquerque

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html

Comment: It worked! Thanks! @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting myself from [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html):

> Code that used
>   custom `Parcelable` objects with `AlarmManager` that might have worked
>   on older versions of Android [will not work on Android N](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209422).
>
> Matthias Urhahn
>   [pointed out](https://twitter.com/d4rken/status/756850908290580480/)
>   [a] workaround: convert the `Parcelable` into a `byte[]` yourself,
>   storing that in the `Bundle`. Then, the OS process will just treat
>   it as some random `byte[]`. [This Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18000094/115145)
>   shows the technique.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Parcelable/Marshall) also illustrates this technique.