# How to pass ParcelableArrayList from Fragment to Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, parcelable, android-bundle

I have been trying to find the way to pass a ParcelableArrayList from one Fragment to Another and for some reason when I receive the ParcelableArrayList it's empty. I have checked many posts about this problem but I don't make it work.

This is my Activity that holds the Fragments in a FrameLayout:

```
package com.blumonpay.restaurant.customer.presentation.activities;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.blumonpay.android.mifel.restaurante.R;
import com.blumonpay.restaurant.customer.presentation.fragments.ShowPayMethodsFragment;

public class PayMethodsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Fragment showFragment;
    private Fragment addFragment;
   


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_methods);

        showFragment = ShowPayMethodsFragment.getInstance(this);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frameLayout, showFragment)
                .commit();
        
    }

    public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

   
}
```

This is how I'm trying to pass the ArrayList in my first Fragment:

```
        Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
        dataBundle.putParcelableArrayList("cardsList", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) list);
        dataBundle.putInt("position",position);
        ShowDetailedPayMethodFragment showDetailPayMethod = ShowDetailedPayMethodFragment.getInstance(context);
        showDetailPayMethod.setArguments(dataBundle);
        ((PayMethodsActivity)context).switchFragment(showDetailPayMethod);
```

*As you can see I'm also passing an `int` value which I can receive with no problem at all.*

Then, this is the second Fragment where I'm receiving the data (`ParcelableArrayList` and the `int` value):

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_detailed_pay_method, container, false);

        if (this.getArguments()!=null) {
            cardsList = this.getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("cardsList");
            positionList = this.getArguments().getInt("position");
        }
        
        cardsBannerAdapter = new CustomCardsBannerAdapter(context, cardsList);
        cardsViewPager.setAdapter(cardsBannerAdapter);

        initSlider();
        return v;
    }
```

For some reason the List is empty when I get to this point, the only value I'm getting is `this.getArguments().getInt("position");` (int value)

And finally this is my POJO class `Cards`:

```
package com.blumonpay.restaurant.customer.domain.model;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Cards implements Parcelable {

    private String cardNumber;
    private String cardType;
    private String cardBrand;
    private String cardExpirationDate;
    private String cardHolderName;

    public Cards(String cardNumber, String cardType, String cardBrand, String cardExpirationDate, String cardHolderName) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        this.cardType = cardType;
        this.cardBrand = cardBrand;
        this.cardExpirationDate = cardExpirationDate;
        this.cardHolderName = cardHolderName;
    }

    public String getCardNumber() {
        return cardNumber;
    }

    public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    }

    public String getCardType() {
        return cardType;
    }

    public void setCardType(String cardType) {
        this.cardType = cardType;
    }

    public String getCardBrand() {
        return cardBrand;
    }

    public void setCardBrand(String cardBrand) {
        this.cardBrand = cardBrand;
    }

    public String getCardExpirationDate() {
        return cardExpirationDate;
    }

    public void setCardExpirationDate(String cardExpirationDate) {
        this.cardExpirationDate = cardExpirationDate;
    }

    public String getCardHolderName() {
        return cardHolderName;
    }

    public void setCardHolderName(String cardHolderName) {
        this.cardHolderName = cardHolderName;
    }



    protected Cards(Parcel in) {
        cardNumber = in.readString();
        cardType = in.readString();
        cardBrand = in.readString();
        cardExpirationDate = in.readString();
        cardHolderName = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(cardNumber);
        dest.writeString(cardType);
        dest.writeString(cardBrand);
        dest.writeString(cardExpirationDate);
        dest.writeString(cardHolderName);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Cards> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Cards>() {
        @Override
        public Cards createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Cards(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Cards[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Cards[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Any clue of what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same in kotlin, with the Cards.java intact. The list gets passed. Here is the snippet.
Could you try and compare?

In first fragment as an example:

```
val item = Cards("gfhfhfhfh", "", "", "", "")
val list = ArrayList<Cards>()
list.add(item
```

Passing it as: (no explicit cast)

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("list",list)
```

In the next fragment:

```
val l = arguments?.getParcelableArrayList<Cards>("list")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, [How to marshall and unmarshall Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18000093/9167710), `Parcelable` object is not stable which might well be the reason that you cannot pass it from one activity to another. I faced similar problem recently and used the same post to solve my problem. Basically in steps:
1. You need to marshall the `Parcelable` object in the first `Activity` as :

```
byte[] bytes = marshall(parcelableObj);

intentOpenSecondActivity.putExtra(SOME_KEY, bytes);
```

2. You need to unmarshall it in the second `Activity` as :

```
byte[] bytes = getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray(SOME_KEY);

parcelableObj = unmarshall(bytes, ParcelableObject.CREATOR);
```