# Error in casting Object[] to byte[]

Tags: java, object, casting, byte

I want to read from database a `pdf`, which stores as `BLOB` and I want to get `List<bytes[]>`

```
session.beginTransaction();
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",id));
final ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList().add(
        Projections.property("bdoc"));
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
List<Object[]> list = criteria.list();
List<byte[]> listBytes = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
for (Object[] item : list) {
    listBytes.add((byte[]) item[0]);
}
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

But I get an error in this line  `for (Object[] item : list) {`

**[ERROR] [B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;**

I've debugged and I do read data from database: my `List<Object[]> list = criteria.list()` is not empty.
But I can not convert from  `List<Object[]>` to `List<bytes[]>`. What am I doing wrong? Help me please to resolve my problem.

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736058/java-object-to-byte-and-byte-to-object-converter-for-tokyo-cabinet can help

Comment: From the error it appears that the list contains arrays of bytes (i.e. `[B`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Means you are indeed getting bytearray and you are trying to convert it into Object array.

Comment: I wrote List<byte[]> list = criteria.list(); and everything is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused because [`Criteria.list()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#list%28%29) returns a raw `List`. As a result, you are able to write code that causes a `ClassCastException`. With a properly typed list, the compiler would prevent this.

As explained in the other answer, the text `[B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object` means that a `byte[]` is being cast to an `Object[]`, which is not allowed.

This means that your list contains `byte[]` objects and you should declare it as such:

```
List<byte[]> list = criteria.list();
```

In addition, the contents of your for-loop now look incorrect:

```
listBytes.add((byte[]) item[0]);
```

Since `item` is now a `byte[]`, it's not correct to cast a `byte` to a `byte[]`. Perhaps you need to remove the array index `[0]`.