# Pass Serializable Object to Pending Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization

I am trying to send a serializable object to a pending Intent.  The problem is the alarm being received is returning as null.  Even though the Alarm implements the serializable interface.

```
//AlarmService.java

Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("alarm", alarm);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getAlarmTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

The alarm being received is null.

```
//AlarmAlertBroadcastReceiver.java

public class AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Alarm alarm = (Alarm)intent.getExtras().getSerializable("alarm");
    }
}
```

---

Edit:
Some more things I've tried is as follows, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
//AlarmService.java

Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
myIntent.putExtra("alarm", alarm);
myIntent.setAction("abc.xyz");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getAlarmTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

The alarm being received is null.

```
//AlarmAlertBroadcastReceiver.java

public class AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Alarm alarm = (Alarm)intent.getExtras().getSerializable("alarm");
      //Alarm alarm = (Alarm)intent.getSerializableExtra("alarm");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass custom Serializable object to BroadcastReceiver via PendingIntent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209579/how-to-pass-custom-serializable-object-to-broadcastreceiver-via-pendingintent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using android Nougat so none of these answers quite worked.  I ended up passing the objects in a byte array.

```
//AlarmService.java

Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeObject(alarm);
    out.flush();
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    myIntent.putExtra("alarm", data);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getAlarmTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Then I received the Byte[]

```
//AlarmAlertBroadcastReceiver.java

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(intent.getByteArrayExtra("alarm"));
    ObjectInput in = null;
    Alarm alarm = null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        alarm = (Alarm)in.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not parse object to jsonString and pass to intent?

Answer (score 20):

There are known issues with putting custom  objects into an `Intent` that is then passed to `AlarmManager` or `NotificationManager` or other external applications. You can try to wrap your custom object in a `Bundle`, as this will sometimes work. For example, change your code to:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                             AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("alarm", alarm);
myIntent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
```

and in `AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.onReceive()`:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
if (bundle != null) {
    Alarm alarm = (Alarm)bundle.getSerializable("alarm");
}
```

If this does not work (and this should work on most Android versions/devices, but not all, especially very new ones), you will need to convert your `Serializeable` object into a `byte[]` and put the `byte[]` into the extras.

There are dozens of examples of how to do that on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you!  This helped.  I ended up passing my object with a byte[], because I'm running Nougat on my phone.  Which worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have `putSerializable` in Bundle. And you are try to `getSerializable` from intent.

```
For set : `myIntent.putExtra("alarm", alarm);` 
For get : `(Alarm)intent.getExtras().getSerializableExtra("alarm");` 
Also make sure your `Alarm` calss have `implements` with `Serializable`.
```

try that.

Comment: That's a good thought.  I just tried it and it still returns null.

Comment: I've tried `(Alarm)intent.getSerializableExtra("alarm")` and `(Alarm)intent.getExtras().getSerializable("alarm")` for receiving and `myIntent.putExtra("alarm", alarm);` for sending.  It's all null...

Comment: I can't call `intent.getExtras().getSerializableExtra("alarm")` I can only do `intent.getExtras().getSerializable("alarm")` or `intent.getSerializableExtra("alarm")`, but both don't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Intent putExtra (String name, 
                Parcelable value)

Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Try to use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: Thanks, but the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT didn't seem to make it want to work either

Answer (score 0):

It's a suggestion, you can try parcelabler which is more efficient and tailored for android specific needs. 
so get your model class parceled [here.](http://www.parcelabler.com/)
after that paste in into your project and then pass it to another activity using either bundle

```
bundle.putParcelable(KEY_PARCEL, detailModelsList.get(position));
```

or

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Parcelaber",myList);
```

Comment: I might try that if I can't get this Serializable thing to work

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things I want to suggest:

1. You need to set `Action` to your intent, such as: `yourIntent.setAction("abc.xyz")`
2. You should use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Those were some good thoughts.  For some reason they still don't seem to want to work :(

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with any other request id other than 0

for eg

```
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestID , myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent!=null && intent.hasExtra("alarm")){
        Alarm alarm = (Alarm)intent.getExtras().getSerializable("alarm");
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's a good thought.  For some reason it's still returning null.