# Launching another application

Tags: java, android

I want to launch another application and put extras. I try did this :

```
private void open() {
 openApplication(getActivity(), "com.app.package.here");
}

public void openApplication(Context context, String packageN) {
 Intent i = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageN);
 if (i != null) {
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  i.putExtra(PGO_GET, pgo != null ? pgo : pgogb);
  context.startActivity(i);
 } else {
  try {
   context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageN)));
  } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
   context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageN)));
  }
 }
}
```

But it is not working.

In secend activity in loginActivity I have this :

```
  Object ob = getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(PGOOptionsDialog.PGO_GET);
        if (ob != null) {
            if (ob instanceof PGOGet) {
                currentPGO = (PGOGet) ob;
            } else if (ob instanceof PGO) {
                pgodb = (PGO) ob;
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you define your PGO somewhere?

Comment: @gratienasimbahwe yes when I put this extras from one activity to another it works corretly

Comment: are you starting the other app in a an activity of a dialog or service?

Comment: @gratienasimbahwe I want to start new app

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347157/intent-extra-gets-cleared-out-from-unknown-reason) that I had half year ago. For a quick test please try sending String instead of your Serializable.

Comment: Does your app starts but don't get extras, or is it not starting at all?

Comment: don't have extras my apllication is sarting

Comment: Ok, please update your question with code used to read extras in your app.

Comment: I know what is wrong when my secend app is running background and I louch this app I don't have this extras . This is a probleme