# Object return null when putExtra and getSerializable on BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I just want to pop the Title to the notification but this is return null object. I need help pls, my English is very bad I hope everyone will sympathy :D.

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.a.Work.getTitle()' on a null object reference at com.example.a.AlertBrr.onReceive(AlertBrr.java:24)
```

**CreateActivity.class**

```
            Work work = new Work();
            work.setTitle(ctitle.getText().toString());
            work.setDate(edittext.getText().toString());
            work.setContent(ccontent.getText().toString());
            Database database = new Database(CreateActivity.this);
            database.add(work);
            //
            Intent intent = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, AlertBrr.class);
            intent.putExtra("work", work);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CreateActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

**AlertBrr.class:**

```
public class AlertBrr extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Work work = (Work) intent.getSerializableExtra("work");

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "duong")
                .setContentTitle(work.getTitle())
                .setContentText(work.getContent())
                .setContentInfo(work.getDate())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.done);

        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        managerCompat.notify(100, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: What interface does your `Work` class implement? `Serializable` or `Parcelable`?

Comment: @StoyanMilev I implements Serializable

Comment: My project: github.com/duongdduaa/Worklist. Please

Comment: I'll check it out later, sorry. Now I'm at work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha Minh, I've taken a look at your project. Thanks for sharing it, that helped a lot!

To fix this issue you have to wrap the `Work` object into a `Bundle` and then pass the `Bundle` into the `Intnet`. Your code in `CreateActivity#onOptionsItemSelected` should look like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, AlertBrr.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("work", work);
intent.putExtra("work_bundle", bundle);
```

And in `AlertBrr#onReceive`:

```
Bundle workBundle = intent.getParcelableExtra("work_bundle");
Work work = (Work) workBundle.getSerializable("work");
```

Note: I got the idea of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39209699/15106139) stackoverflow answer.

Comment: I tried it but the timing is not working correctly, notification popped up twice. One is right after creating the note, the other is the selected time  xD

Comment: That is because you fire it twice. I thought you want that behavior. Just remove the `sendBroadcast(...)` method in your `CreateActivity#onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: Great. Thank you so much!