# Springboot ClientHttpRequestInterceptor: get request object type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, interceptor, clienthttprequest

I'm working on a springboot project where I need to intercept outgoing http requests and do something with it. I know we can use ClientHttpRequestInterceptor for the same and it works fine too.

But I need to know the **java class type** of the request body that is being sent in the http POST/PUT request. Currently this interceptor only provides a byte array representation of the request object. [Doc here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html#intercept-org.springframework.http.HttpRequest-byte:A-org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution-)

Is there any way I can get to know the java class type of request object/body? Or is there any other better way to do this  other than using the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor?

Updated code sample:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {


@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request,
                             byte[] body,
                             ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
                      throws IOException {

// Do something before service invocation

// I need to get request body's class type but it is just a byte[] here. And the 'HttpRequest' argument doesn't carry any info related to request class type.

ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse = execution.execute(request, body);

// Do something after service invocation    
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for more details?

Comment: Added sample code. Please check.

Comment: Can someone thow some light on this please?? I'm stuck at the same spot and still trying to figure out a way.

Comment: I added the answer for you, all the best

Comment: Not sure about this interceptor. But you have the request object, can't you set an attribute which is the classname of the body which is being set. You can simply get that attribute here.

Answer (score 0):

byte[] is serialized form of your request Object. Just by having byte[] chunk in hand will not help you in determining what kind of class's Object it was. You need to do some thing more -

If you are implementing your ClientHttpRequestInterceptor for your RestTemplate and you have to do some thing with your Request Object - then you must have to convert byte[] body to your object :

How - [Java: object to byte[] and byte[] to object converter (for Tokyo Cabinet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736058/java-object-to-byte-and-byte-to-object-converter-for-tokyo-cabinet/3736091)

Once you have an object in hand then use  instanceof to check if converted Object belongs to your class:

```
if(obj instanceof Your_Class){
   // your class specific code ..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can, the recommended way of doing so; is using ِAspect Oriented Programming **AOP**, which will support you with all details you need about the JointPoint you target; in your case, it will be the method called inside the controller.

Check this example [Spring Boot AOP](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/performance-logging-aspectj-aop/), and also it is better to get your hand dirty with these classes **ProceedingJoinPoint** and **JointPoint**

> To make it simple, you can use this JointPoint class to get the method signature and of course its parameters, for each parameter you have the type also (which you are looking for), moreover you can use the parameter itself to do whatever logic you need. check the following

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(SomeAnnotation)")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        CodeSignature codeSignature = (CodeSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();

        System.out.println("Parameters' Types: " + codeSignature.getParameterTypes);
        System.out.println("Parameters' name: " + codeSignature.getParameterNames()[0]);
        System.out.println("Arguments' value: " + joinPoint.getArgs());

        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

The other way which may help you in your code is by using pure reflection and custom annotation, in that way you can get also the all details from Class of your request, but it may require some more code.

Comment: @ram did you try the solution?