# What 'Content-Type' header to use when serving gzipped files?

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, gzip

I'm serving gzipped copies of my css / javascript files. As per a tutorial, I set the content-type as `application/gzip` when serving these files. However, chrome doesn't seem to un-gzip these files, and for the javascript files I get a lot of 'illegal character' errors. If I view source, I still see the files as compressed, rather than uncompressed.

My question is, what should I set as the content type for these files, in order for the browser to interpret them correctly as gzipped css / js files, and un-gzip them? If I just set `text/javascript` or `text/css`, will the browser still interpret them correctly?

Edit: Full response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: UIBkZT/MuFxsmn+3nVOzEO63rRY99l3traCbMExUgSdGHUrOIPtNp34h1+ujYKmt
x-amz-request-id: 19346C9B01D8FC62
Date: Mon, 12 May 2014 03:59:51 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 May 2014 02:24:54 GMT
ETag: "561080b5e19f6daea2e74fd5a0623c79"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
Content-Length: 5153
Server: AmazonS3
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Compressed content in the response is indicated in the `Content-Encoding`.  The `Content-Type` should remain the same, that is, it should reflect the underlying media type that is compressed.

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

See sections [14.11 Content-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.11) and [3.5 Content Codings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.5) of RFC 2616 for more information.

Comment: I'm already doing that, but it still seems to be not interpreting the script correctly. I've edited to put the full headers in the question

Comment: It gives the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on line 1, and when I check it, I see that it has the file name at that line, e.g `�� aRjquery-1.7.1.min.js�}`. I compressed the files using `gzip -9`, do I need to gzip using a lower setting? Or do I need to delete the filenames from the start of file?

Comment: OK, I see the expected Content-Encoding, but the Content-Type should reflect the underlying media type that is compressed.  Try changing `application/x-gzip` back to `application/javascript`.

Comment: I also see AmazonS3 is the server.  Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442011/serving-gzipped-css-and-javascript-from-amazon-cloudfront-via-s3 is also relevant.