# Chrome complains of MIME type wrong

Tags: browser, download, mime-types

I have created a simple PHP script which downloads files (sends them to the browser).  The script sends the browser the type of document, for example MIME type "application/gz" for example document test.tar.gz

However, on receiving the document Chrome complains:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/gz
```

Am I setting the wrong MIME type?  (Please don't focus on why I'm creating my own download script...just the MIME issue)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600229/what-content-type-header-to-use-when-serving-gzipped-files

Comment: According to [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) the correct MIME type for .gz files is [`application/gzip`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/gzip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VCSjones was correct - I needed to change the MIME type to application/gzip and then Chrome no longer complained.