# Gzip file decompress with web.config (Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, iis, web-config, gzip

I have compressed my react files with `webpack's CompressionPlugin` in `gz` format. Also, I added the following config in `web.config` for reading `gz` files in `IIS`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".js.gz" />
        <remove fileExtension=".css.gz" />
        <remove fileExtension=".png.gz" />
        <remove fileExtension=".jpg.gz" />
        <remove fileExtension=".gif.gz" />
        <remove fileExtension=".svg.gz" />
        <remove fileExtension=".html.gz" />
        <remove fileExtension=".json.gz" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".js.gz" mimeType="application/javascript" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".css.gz" mimeType="text/css" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".png.gz" mimeType="image/png" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg.gz" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".gif.gz" mimeType="image/gif" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg.gz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".html.gz" mimeType="text/html" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json.gz" mimeType="application/json" />
      <!--<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />-->
    </staticContent>
      <rewrite>
          <outboundRules  rewriteBeforeCache="true">
              <rule name="Custom gzip file header">
                  <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CONTENT_ENCODING" pattern=".*" />
                  <conditions>
                      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.gz$" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" value="gzip"/>
              </rule>
          </outboundRules>
          <rules>
              <rule name="Rewrite gzip file">
                  <match url="(.*)"/>
                  <conditions>
                      <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="gzip" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz" matchType="IsFile" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.gz" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

Unfortunately, sometimes, when I clear the cache with `ctrl + f5` in the console, I get the following:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token : main.js.gz

Also, here's the picture of the Sources part of Google Chrome's developer tools:

[image]

Does anyone know where the problem is?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Clear cache get this error? Does it mean that there's no request send to server but get this error? If the site has main.js file, will it report error when request for this file?

Comment: I clear cache and refresh page by `ctrl + f5`. Obviously there is a request for getting the `main.js` and `vendor.js` again. But unfortunately sometimes I get the mentioned error. I don't know why sometimes client can't detect that the files which is sent by the server have `gz` format and should decompress them.

Comment: I ran into this issue with WordPress and gzipped HTML (index.html.gz), I resolved that by storing the original Accept-Encoding header in an extra one (HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING) so I can later on restore the Accept-Encoding header. It's here posted (careful, years old post): https://www.saotn.org/speed-up-wordpress-with-gzip-compression/

Comment: Could be for several reasons. Maybe it's missing the wrong response header.
1) Add the gzip headers for files in a folder. Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69628186/uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-for-js-gz-file-compressed-an
2) Disable static compression in IIS. Else it will compress the already compressed files again.

Comment: @Valderann Thank you for the comment! Actually I think its related to IIS settings for static compression which you mentioned. I should check it!

Comment: @MajidM. I have the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: @Matt It goes back to more than 1 year a go! I don't remember what was the solution exactly, but I know that the problem was related to 2 times compression! 1 time from `web.config` and another from other part of the application.

Comment: @MajidM. np, I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63794100/968379