# Easiest way to save multiple Java objects to a file as key-value pairs?

Tags: java, serialization, key-value-store

I am looking for the simplest key-value store that would allow me to save and retrieve custom objects to/from a file, for example:

```
Set obj1;
Map obj2;
...
Store.saveObject(obj1, "mySet", "myFile.dat");
Store.saveObject(obj2, "myMap", "myFile.dat");
...
obj1 = (Set) Store.getObject("mySet", "myFile.dat");
obj2 = (Map) Store.getObject("myMap", "myFile.dat");
```

Where obj1 and obj2 are just example objects, "mySet" and "myMap" are keys, "myFile.dat" is the file. Is there any library close to this in simplicity? Example code equivalent to my code would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to use a single map which has all your data?

Comment: I need this for any Object - Set and Map were just quick examples

Comment: Berkeley DB is pretty close, although it could be a bit of an overkill, if this is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of combination of [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and [Java serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array). However you might want to [base64 encode/decode](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/08/how-to-encode-and-decode-in-base64-using-java) your byte array.