# File object to byte array - android development

Tags: java, android, file

I need to convert this File object to byte array:

```
File directory=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "");
```

(I need only the names of folders and files on SDcard.)

I have already tried this:

```
 byte[] send=null;
            FileInputStream fis;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(directory);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int readBytes = 0;
            while(readBytes != -1)
            {

                    readBytes = fis.read(buffer);

                if(readBytes > 0)
                {
                    bos.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
                else 
                    break;
            }
            byte[] fileData = bos.toByteArray();
            send=fileData;
```

But it returns this error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard (Is a directory)

Comment: File implements serializable, so perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array might help.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load *the directory* as if it were a file. It's not. What would you expect the contents of the byte array to be?

If you want to find the list of files in a directory, use [`File.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29).

Comment: I wanna make remote file explorer. And I need to get this File object as it is to another phone via bluetooth (and I able to send only byte arrays). Sorry for my english

Comment: @user1681497: The `File` really only knows the path. If you're trying to get the names of the files and folders within it, you'll need to use `File.listFiles()` (or just `File.list()` for strings.)

Comment: Oh, ok... So I have to send the File.list() from one phone to another everytime, when the user opens a folder :(

Comment: @user1681497: Well you *could* basically send the entire file system, in your own custom format - that does sound like a good idea to me though. Perhaps send the full structure in terms of file names as a recursive tree structure, and have a separate call to get file contents.