# Using copy of objects in Java

Tags: java, object, copy

My last last java assignment that I am all okay except this two lines below. What is the intend of it, and how would I do that? Anybody giving a clue about that are appreciated.

I am not allowed to use primitives on this one

> Do not assign given Wrapper Class objects (Integer, Char, Double, etc.) directly. Use a copy of objects.

Yesterday ı talked to my assistant and he sad that when you assign the value like this:

> Integer asd ;
>   asd = new Integer(10);

Instead of this:

> Integer asd ;
>   asd = 10 ;

it copies the object and assigns the value. Then (I think) the old record gets eligible for garbage collector.

Comment: What language? Can you post your code?

Comment: Searching for "java copy objet" finds lots of information, like [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java), [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_\(Java_method\))

Answer (score 1):

I guess it means you should use methods like [Integer#parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) and [Integer#valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) instead of creating the object directly using a constructor.

Comment: Or it could mean, "don't use autoboxing". I.e. don't do `Integer myInt = 10;`.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda sounds like they're fishing for

```
object.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to serialize and unserialize it. Then you can get another copy of the object. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2836659/940313

btw, `Object.clone()` is `protected` by default, so you may not be able to copy an object in this way, unless the corresponding class really implements `clone()` and declares it as `public`.