# Android serialization - will this work with a whole instance of an object?

Tags: android, serialization

The response I got to my previous question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489956/sending-data-structure-through-byte-android
states that I should look into serialization for converting my data to a byte array for transfer via bluetooth.

I have been looking into it but can't find any definite answer that states whether I am able to transfer a whole instance of an object, I was originally thinking of sending several arrays but now I am thinking maybe I can just create an object:

"Test"
parameters:

Test Name - String

Questions - Array of Strings

Question Answers - Array of Strings

Correct Answers - Array of Ints

My programming isn't that great so I was wondering, could I create this class, let the user on one device construct an object and then pass THAT object itself on through serialization (as shown in [Java Serializable Object to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array))

Will this ACTUALLY fully work and give me a whole object on the other system from which I can access the data elements I need?

Sorry if this is a stupid question but as I stated before my programming isn't that great and so I get confused sometimes :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could I create
>   this class, let the user on one device construct an object and then
>   pass THAT object itself on through serialization

Short answer: Yes

But don't forget that class have to implement Serializable interface or **NotSerializableException** will be thrown.

> Will this ACTUALLY fully work and give me a whole object on the other
>   system from which I can access the data elements I need?

Yes but this "other system" must know about this class. So if you create class

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {

   private String name;
   private int age;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Application that want to deserialize object, must have this class in build path, simply said.

Comment: well the application i'm making will be the same for both devices, just a start screen that identifies whether you are the 'teacher' or 'pupil', as they need to send back data too.

so are you saying this is possible then (and i shouldn't run into any real roadblocks)

Comment: @aspiring_programmer i think no you need to try it.

Comment: ahh wicked! I'll give it a go now, report back when I'm finished! cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531281/serialization-really-confused-android i'm confused :(