# how to recover BufferedReader object from ByeArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, deserialization, bufferedreader, bytearrayinputstream

I have written a code to stub the `System.out.println` and passing the object of `BuffredReader` into it. 
My question is how to recover the `BufferedReader` object?

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    // stubbing the default print statement
    ByteArrayOutputStream outcontent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outcontent);

      //createing a BufferedReader obj and passing to print
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
      System.out.println(br);

      //trying to get the value from the outcontent and 
      // but i need to serialise this to BufferedReader
      System.err.println(outContent.toString());

    }
  }
```

I have tried to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394555/serialize-deserialize-java-object-through-network-and-byte-array) but i am getting the error `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 6A617661`

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, you should try something like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BuffererdBeader( new InputStreamReader(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream( outcontent.toByteArray() ) ) );
```

Comment: doing so, the reader seems not to have any readLine() method to it

Comment: yes, but if i write your code the reader.readLine is not acceprting any value from the console

Comment: Why would it do anything with the console? It just reads what your program writes to `System.out`.