# How to put multiple elements into byte[] in java

Tags: java, http, http-headers, arrays

How can I put multiple elements into `byte[]`? I have the following 3 elements: 1) `String data` , 2) `String status` and 3) `HashMap<String,String> headers`, which need to be passed to `setContent(byte[] data)` as byte arrays. The following is the code in which I would like to use the previous 3 parameters as input for `statusResult.setContent()`:

```
public void onSuccess(ClientResponse clientResponse){
      String data=clientResponse.getMessage();
      String status=String.valueOf(clientResponse.getStatus());
      HashMap<String,String> headers=clientResponse.getHeaders();

    // Now StatusResult is a class where we need to pass all this data,having only getters and
   //  setters for Content,so here in the next line i need to pass data,status and headers as 
  //   a byte[] to setContent.

       statusResult.setContent(byte[]);
}
```

Can somebody help me to resolve this out?

Comment: What elements you want to put in `data`? It's not clear..

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun i wnat to put the string message received from the Response into data,it will be small line as "hello world"

Comment: You need to serialize objects before you put them in the byte[]. Do you really know what is going to happen with those bytes after you pass them to that object as serialized data? Is that object going to interpret them in a proper manner?

Comment: @Ricardo a different class will call statusResult.getContent() to get data,status and header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is serialization in a crude way. I would suggest the following:

1. Create **a class encapsulating the three elements**.
2. Make sure that class `implements` `serializable` interface.
3. Use the following code [*taken from* [this post]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2836659/750040) to **create a byte array** as you wished, and read the object back from byte array (*which, although you have not specified as requirement, but it needs mention for the sake of completeness*)

> ```
> ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
> ObjectOutput out = null;
> try {
>   //Assuming that bos is the object to be seriaized
>   out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
>   out.writeObject(yourObject);
>   byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
>   ...
> } finally {
>   try {
>     if (out != null) {
>       out.close();
>     }
>   } catch (IOException ex) {
>     // ignore close exception
>   }
>   try {
>     bos.close();
>   } catch (IOException ex) {
>     // ignore close exception
>   }
> }
> //Create object from bytes:
>
> ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourBytes);
> ObjectInput in = null;
> try {
>   in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
>   Object o = in.readObject(); 
>   ...
> } finally {
>   try {
>     bis.close();
>   } catch (IOException ex) {
>     // ignore close exception
>   }
>   try {
>     if (in != null) {
>       in.close();
>     }
>   } catch (IOException ex) {
>     // ignore close exception
>   }
> }
> ```