# Store java Object as clob and retrieve

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, clob

i am having a table in oracle. in that table one of the column is to store clob data. and in that clob column, 
have to insert object as clob.

that object should be saved as clob and have to retrive again as object.

In java is there any possible to store Obect as clob.

i had tried the example as per [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/299447/JDBC/databases/insert-data-Oracle-Clob)

```
import java.sql.*;   
import java.io.*;   
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet;  
import oracle.sql.CLOB;  
public class TestOracleClob implements Serializable{   
 public static void main(String[] args)   
 {   

  //create table test (id integer,content clob);  
  System.out.println("-------------------insert -----------------");  
  try{  
   DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("oracle server",  
   "loginid", "loginpassword");   
  //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

  con.setAutoCommit(false);  
  //Ok 1  
  String sql="insert into test values(1,empty_clob())";  
  Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);  
  System.out.println("-------------------insert -----------------");  
  String sqll="select content from test where id=1 for update";      
  ResultSet rss=stmt.executeQuery(sqll);  

  if(rss.next()){  
   //CLOB clob = ((OracleResultSet)rss).getCLOB(1);  
 oracle.sql.CLOB  clob= (oracle.sql.CLOB)rss.getClob("content");  
   clob.putString(1,"here is a string which contains more than 4000 character");  
   sql="update test set content=? where id=1";  
   PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);  
   pstmt.setClob(1,clob);  
   pstmt.executeUpdate();  
   pstmt.close();  
  }    
  con.commit();  

  //Ok 2  
  //String sql1="insert into test values(2,empty_clob())";  
  //ResultSet rs3=stmt.executeQuery(sql1);  
  String sql12="insert into test values(?,?)";  
  PreparedStatement pstmt1=con.prepareStatement(sql12);  
  pstmt1.setInt(1,2);  
  pstmt1.setClob(2,oracle.sql.CLOB.empty_lob());  
  pstmt1.executeUpdate();  

  String sqll2="select content from test where id=2 for update";  
  ResultSet rss2=stmt.executeQuery(sqll2);  
  if(rss2.next()){  
   CLOB clob = ((OracleResultSet)rss2).getCLOB(1);  
   clob.putString(1,"affffffffffdfdfdfdddddddffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdddfff");  
   String sql1="update test set content=? where id=2";  
   PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(sql1);  
   pstmt.setClob(1,clob);  
   pstmt.executeUpdate();  
   pstmt.close();  
  }  
  con.commit();  
  rss.close();  
  rss2.close();  
  pstmt1.close();  
  rs.close();  
  stmt.close();  
  con.close();  
  System.out.println("-------------insert ok-------------");  
  }catch(Exception e){  
   System.out.println("insert:"+e);  
  }  
  System.out.println("-------------------query -----------------");  
  try{  
  String content="";  
  //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
  DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());  
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("oracleserver",  
   "id", "pass");   

  Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
  String sql="select content from test where id=1";  
  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);  
  if(rs.next()){  
   CLOB clob = ((OracleResultSet)rs).getCLOB(1);  
   if(clob!=null){  
   Reader is=clob.getCharacterStream();  
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(is);  
   String s=br.readLine();  
   while(s!=null){  
    content+=s+",";  
    s=br.readLine();  
    }  
   }  

  }  
  rs.close();  
  stmt.close();  
  con.close();  
  System.out.println("clob:"+content);  
  System.out.println("-------------query ok-------------");  
  }catch(Exception ee){  
   System.out.println("Exception:"+ee);  
  }  

 }  
 }
```

but in that they add String to clob. but i want to add my object to clob. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array

Comment: Is it possible to add this to clob

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could directly serialize your object into the clob like so:

```
Object o = new Object(); // anything serializable
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clob.setAsciiStream(0));
out.writeObject(o);
out.close();
```

And read vice versa:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clob.getAsciiStream());
Object o = in.readObject();
in.close();
```