# converting files to byte array and sending it as a byte[][] array

Tags: java, file, io, arrays

I am having a problem in the following conversion. The file becomes scrambled and loses all its info.

here is the method I am using to convert:

```
private byte[] readFileToArray(Object object) throws IOException{

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
      ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutput); 

      objectOutput.writeObject(object);
      objectOutput.flush(); 
      objectOutput.close(); 
      byteArrayOutput.close();

      byte [] data = byteArrayOutput.toByteArray();

      return data;
}
```

what should I do so that i don't lose the info in the files?

Comment: Please, could you post a more complete example?  Your code is correct at first sight, so maybe your problem is with whatever you are feeding it with (what is the `object` variable?)

Comment: I think the answer can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array