# How to convert Strings and a Bitmap to a byte array?

Tags: java, android

I'm using a GoogleApiClient MessageApi method which accepts an arbitrary payload specified as a byte array.

For my payload I have some strings and a Bitmap that I want to transfer all together in one go.

What options are there available for packaging the strings and bitmaps and converting to a byte array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array

Answer (score 0):

A Bitmap can be converted to bytes through [copyPixelsToBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)). A string has [getBytes](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)).