# How to convert Message type to byte[]?

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, byte

I want to convert Message type to `byte[]` without going through string, because I need it for performance issues.

I should not pass through string (`Message` to string to `byte[]`).

Message type:javax.jms.MessageConsumer

Comment: this javax.mail.Message ?? or what Message ? mention it clearly

Comment: In fact, I don't know, I'm working with this code https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB300/Sending+and+Receiving+Messages+Using+Queues

Comment: **1)** You need to know what are you working with **2)** If your message implements serializeable then try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array

Comment: I found that, the method use javax.jms.MessageConsumer, but the message doesn't implement serializeable

Comment: Saw your code link, i believe its **javax.jms.TextMessage** [child of **javax.jms.Message**]

Comment: no, it's not, in the link , they convert consumer.receive() (Message) to TextMessage

Comment: Decide what is the exact class you want to convert into byte[]. Come back and type the class name and exact package. till then we have no idea how  to help you. packageName.subpackageName...ClassName

Comment: anyway, have you any idea how to convert  javax.jms.TextMessage to byte[] ?

Comment: NOT a good way but... in the line below *// create the message to send*, **Create and Send** an instance of **javax.jms.BytesMessage** http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html instead of TextMessage

Comment: If you have a TextMessage, you already have a String.  You can't avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'Message' class implements Serializeable, then you can convert it directly into a byte[].

In Java, Serialization is the conversion of an object to a series of bytes, so that the object can be easily saved to persistent storage or streamed across a communication link. The byte stream can then be deserialized - converted into a replica of the original object.

Here's a [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) to a nice tutorial on serialization in Java.

Comment: Im working with  javax.jms.MessageConsumer, and it's not serializeable