# How to convert an android object into a byte array and do it back?

Tags: android, serialization, wear-os, android-bundle

I am using message api to send messages between a smart phone and a smart watch. As it can send only byte arrays as data, I would like to convert an object into byte array while sending and reverse the conversion while receiving.

I have used the below code which I got from internet. But I am getting java.io.NotSerializableException. Is there any better way to do it?

My object will have a string value and an android bundle. Both needs to be sent from one device and received at the other end.

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(Object obj) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
            bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            if (oos != null) {
                oos.close();
            }
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
        }
        return bytes;
    }

public static Event toObject(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Event obj = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            obj = (Event) ois.readObject();
        } finally {
            if (bis != null) {
                bis.close();
            }
            if (ois != null) {
                ois.close();
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Is your object Serializable? Said that, why not make your methods receive `Serializable obj` instead?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. Using ApacheUtils  worked for me:                                        

To Serialize:

byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize(yourObject);
deserialize:

YourObject yourObject = (YourObject) SerializationUtils.deserialize(byte[] data)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void toByteArray(Object obj) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/your_file.bin"));
    outputstream.write((byte[]) obj);
    Log.i("...","Done");
    outputstream.close();
}
```

Try this may it'll work for you, it will store your file in downloads folder in your smartphone.