# How to use calendar type in realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I am creating a model where i'm trying to store gregorian calendar value in a column, but its showing me error, Calendar Datatype not supported by realmProxcy.

```
private String alarmName;
private Boolean alarmActive = true;
private Date alarmTime;
private String alarmTonePath = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM).toString();
private Boolean alarmVibrate = true;
private  Calendar cal;
```

> @PrimaryKey
>       public int alarmid;

**Error:(30, 8) error: Type 'java.util.Calendar' of field 'cal' is not supported**
how can i store this calendar value and fetch it

Comment: Realm does not support to Object Calendar

Comment: You can store it as a `Date`

Comment: Thank you I have stored it as, Date only and converting it to calendar while accessing it in my function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **really** need to store a `Calendar` instance, you can take advantage of it being a `Serializable` and the possibility of storing `byte[]` arrays in Realm objects - **serialize** your `Calendar` to byte array for storage and **deserialize** from byte array when accessing data.

Your object would look like this:

```
class MyRealmObject extends RealmObject {
    private String alarmName;
    private Boolean alarmActive = true;
    private Date alarmTime;
    private String alarmTonePath = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM).toString();
    private Boolean alarmVibrate = true;
    private byte[] serializedCalendar;

    public Calendar getCalendar() {
        return deserializeCalendar(serializedCalendar);
    }

    public void setCalendar(Calendar calendar) {
        this.serializedCalendar = serializeCalendar(calendar);
    }
}
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2836659/4191629) on `Object`<>`byte[]`serialization/deserialization on how to implement methods:

```
byte[] serializeCalendar(Calendar c);
Calendar deserializeCalendar(byte[] arr);
```

Comment: This is what i was actually looking for, but i have implemented using a method toCalendar function as below 

public static Calendar toCalendar(Date date){
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(date);
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "toCalendar: "+cal);
        return cal;
    }

Which is the best way @maciekjanusz

Answer (score 0):

Realm database supports only `Date` class. You have to evaluate your `Calendar` instance to `Date` instance.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = cal.getTime(); //save it to realm
```

From Realm documentation:

> Realm supports the following field types: boolean, byte, short, int, long, float, double, String, **Date** and byte[]. The integer types byte, short, int, and long are all mapped to the same type (long actually) within Realm. Moreover, subclasses of RealmObject and RealmList are supported to model relationships.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#field-types

Comment: thank you,
yeah i have tried it but, i'm trying to store Calendar object, not just date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Calendar, use Date from calendar.getTime(), if necessary store Calendar object converter to other type for save and read convert. Example:

```
public static Calendar toCalendarFromDate(Date date){ 
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);
  return cal;
}
```

Comment: HI Thiago, i have implemented the same but, not able to store time along with the date so that i can convert it back to the calendar